# asp.net - Bind to a linq datasource and add external column

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql

I have a databound control which displays a grid. The grid is bound to a linq to sql data source. I use the following code:

```
PaymentsDataContext data = new PaymentsDataContext();
            var q = from act in data.activations
                    where act.approved != true
                    orderby act.activationDate ascending
                    select new {activationID = act.activationID, userName = act.userName,
                    brokerName = act.broker.brokerName, existingAccount = act.existingAccount,
                    activationDate = act.activationDate, brokerUser = act.brokerUser, approved = act.approved};
            activationPending.DataSource = q;
            activationPending.DataBind();
```

I want to add another column to the grid. I want to show the user's email address.
I get it like so:

```
var member = System.Web.Security.Membership.GetUser(username);
string email = member.Email;
```

How could I add this as a field in the grid, since it's not in the Payment DB at all?

Comment: What grid component are you using? Some have the ability to add calculated columns without they're being in the bound data source.

Comment: It's an asp.net wrapper for jqGrid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
var q = from act in data.activations
                    where act.approved != true
                    orderby act.activationDate ascending
                    select new {activationID = act.activationID, userName = act.userName,
                    brokerName = act.broker.brokerName, 
                    existingAccount = act.existingAccount,
                    activationDate = act.activationDate, brokerUser = act.brokerUser,
                    approved = act.approved, 
                    email = System.Web.Security.Membership.GetUser(act.userName).Email };
```

since you already bin `q` and not `data.activations` this adds the external column to the grid.

Edit : 
Because of the new added column your template of the grid view must have a place 
to accept it you can add this manually like :

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true">
<Columns>
.
.
<asp:BoundField DataField="email" HeaderText="email" 
            SortExpression="email" />
.
.
</Columns>
 </asp:GridView>
```

or set the property of the gridview named AutoGenerateColumns to true

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true">
    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: I hoped you were right, but no. I get a null object ref exception.

Comment: If act.userName is not guranteed to return an eMail-Adress via GetUser then this can happen... I need to think a bit about this...

Comment: It is guranteed. Both username and email address are 'Not NULL' in both the DB itself and the DAL. Even if that statment was not really true, I checked the current table and every user has an email address.

Answer (score 0):

you can write the Extension method and use it in your select. Check this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279701/linq-extension-methods-vs-linq-syntax)

```
 private Func<DataClasses.Activations, String> GetUserEmail(string username)
 {
    return System.Web.Security.Membership.GetUser(username).Email;
 }

 PaymentsDataContext data = new PaymentsDataContext();
        var q = from act in data.activations
                where act.approved != true
                orderby act.activationDate ascending
                select new {activationID = act.activationID, userName = act.userName,
                brokerName = act.broker.brokerName, existingAccount = act.existingAccount,
                activationDate = act.activationDate, brokerUser = act.brokerUser, approved = act.approved, 
                Email = GetUserEmail(act.username)};
```

Comment: This might work, but I must say I'm in over my head with that thread. I don't know linq that well and I have no idea what they are going on about. Any chance you can point me to a specific answer or part of an answer.