# LINQ Vs. Lambda Expression

Tags: linq

From my understanding, we have LINQ and Lambda expressions.
Is it more advisable to use Lambda expression as they provide more functionality that LINQ may not.

```
    LINQ vs Lambda
```

Comment: If you want to ask about specific difference between them - go ahead, otherwise - the question [or a sequence of statements actually] is way to broad, and might be subjective as well.

Comment: You should rephrase that question. As dknaack said you probably mean "query vs. method syntax". And I'm pretty sure this question has been asked before.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linq Extension methods vs Linq syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279701/linq-extension-methods-vs-linq-syntax)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In our applications we tend to mix and match them based on developer preference. My rule of thumb is that if the query requires Join or Group By I use Lamda, if it's a simple filtered statement I use LINQ.

Both will result in an SQL statement in the end, I'd recommend http://www.linqpad.net/ to see the query and execution plan that results from your LINQ or Lamda statement.

Comment: I'm pretty much the opposite. I find the linq syntax for joining and grouping to be much easier to read than the equivalent direct calls to the extension methods, whereas simple filtering and projection is typically easier in LINQ.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean the `query` vs. `method` syntax.

The compiler will translate the query syntax into the method syntax. The performance is the same.

```
var x = from p in XYZ where p.Property == "SomeValue"
```

is the same as

```
var x = XYZ.Where(x => x.Property == "SomeValue")
```

This is more a question of syntax and depends on that you want to do. 
The possebilities are the same, the performance is the same. Sometime the method syntax is
easier to read and sometimes the query syntax.