# Which one is better lambda expressions or

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, lambda

I have following LINQ to SQL query expression

```
from msg in TblUserMessages 
join user in Aspnet_Users on msg.FromUserID equals user.UserId
select new {
       msg.FromUserID, 
       msg.ToUserID, 
       msg.MessageLocationID, 
       msg.MessageID, 
       user.UserName
       }
```

And following LINQ method expression:

```
TblUserMessages
.Join (
  Aspnet_Users, 
  msg => msg.FromUserID, 
  user => user.UserId, 
  (msg, user) => 
     new  
     {
        FromUserID = msg.FromUserID, 
        ToUserID = msg.ToUserID, 
        MessageLocationID = msg.MessageLocationID, 
        MessageID = msg.MessageID, 
        UserName = user.UserName
     }
)
```

Both of these return same result set. Which is e.g. :

```
82522f05-2650-466a-a430-72e6c9fb68b7
6b2a174a-8141-43d2-b3ad-5b199bcbfcae
1
1
waheed
```

Which one is better to use. The `FIRST` one or the `SECOND` one.

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They are equivalent. They don't just return the same result set - they compile to the same code.

Use query expressions or dot notation for individual cases depending on readability. For joins, I find the dot notation quite cumbersome - but I use it for situations where I only have one or two clauses (usually where/select). Even with two clauses (usually where *and* select) I find dot notation nice if you then need to use it anyway. For example, I like:

```
var query = people.Where(person => person.Age > 18)
                  .Select(person => person.Name)
                  .Skip(100)
                  .Take(10);
```

over

```
var query = (from person in people
             where person.Age > 18
             select person.Name)
            .Skip(100)
            .Take(10);
```

For more complicated queries (e.g. joins) I'd probably just separate the two:

```
var baseQuery = from person in people
                where person.Age > 18
                join company on person.CompanyId equals company.CompanyId
                select new { person.Name, company.Name };

var fullQuery = baseQuery.Skip(100)
                         .Take(10);
```

I just find this separation makes it easier to read.

I believe it's really useful for developers to understand at least the basics of what query expressions do - the fact that they're basically translations into dot notation, and that the language itself doesn't know anything about LINQ to Objects, LINQ to SQL etc; it's just a case of following an appropriate pattern. It's a great bit of design, which means query expressions only affect one little bit of the language specification.

Answer (score 3):

There's no *better* one. Use what you like. I would, in this case, go with the 'query' syntax, since I think it's more readable than the second one. Moreover, since we're writing SQL anyway, I think this syntax resembles it better. But I'm sure others will disagree and tend to choose the lamda version.

I *usually* go with the latter syntax btw, since I prefer the lambda syntax cause it is often more readable and shorter.

See also [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630045/linq-dot-notation-vs-query-expression/630065#630065).

Comment: The lambda expression is not shorter. If i have more joins then it become very very long. I think you will agree with me.

Comment: Yes, I agree. That's why I said '(...) is *often* more readable and shorter' :)

Answer (score 2):

I'd always go for the more readable option and in this case I think its the LINQ snippet.

Answer (score 2):

Both will perform equally well, but I will prefer the first since it's easier to read and understand.

Answer (score 1):

Whichever you find easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

"write your code, then measure it to find out what to refactor." Have you measured both? 
Better is subjective.

Are you finding a problem with either one that is making you want to choose one over the other?

Answer (score 0):

There IS one little difference between the two types of syntax. The query expression one will take **longer** to compile because the compiler has to transform it into the dot syntax. Of course, it is almost completely immaterial because:

1. the compilation overhed is minimal,
2. the emitted IL that runtime needs to deal with is exactly the same for both cases.

Answer (score 0):

I use Lambda Expressions when I have to build query dynamically, and LINQ to SQL when query is fully known.

```
IQueryable<IncomeDetailsEntity> query;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(regioncode))
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(compcode))
    {
        query = db.IncomeDetailsEntities.Where(i => i.RegionCode == regioncode && i.CompanyCode == compcode);
    }
    else
    {
        query = db.IncomeDetailsEntities.Where(i => i.RegionCode == regioncode);
    }
}
else
{
    query = db.IncomeDetailsEntities;
}
return query.Select(i => new { i.RegionCode, i.Budget });
```