# Difference between ".OrderBy(p => p.Id)" and "orderby p.Id ascending"

Tags: linq

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Which LINQ syntax do you prefer? Fluent or Query Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214500/which-linq-syntax-do-you-prefer-fluent-or-query-expression)
>   [LINQ: Dot Notation vs Query Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630045/linq-dot-notation-vs-query-expression)

What is the difference between the two methods of sorting in Linq?  Is one better than the other performance wise?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The query syntax is syntactical sugar that gets converted to the method approach. There's no difference, use whatever style suits your needs.

From the [LINQ Query Syntax versus Method Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397947.aspx) MSDN article:

> there is no semantic difference
>   between method syntax and query
>   syntax. In addition, some queries,
>   such as those that retrieve the number
>   of elements that match a specified
>   condition, or that retrieve the
>   element that has the maximum value in
>   a source sequence, can only be
>   expressed as method calls.