# GroupBy in LINQ and set property

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I have such class:

```
public class Foo
{
  public string Regn{get;set;}

  public string DocName{get;set;}

  ...
}
```

In the my application this class uses with IEnumerable:

```
IEnumerable<Foo> items;
```

How to get new IEnumerable, where for all items with the same Regn and DocName property DocName sets like this(only if objects with same DocName >1):

```
item.DocName=item.DocName+".1";//+"2",etc.
```

**[UPDATE]**
Input sample:

```
Regn DocName
1    1
1    2
1    2
2    5
2    5
2    6
```

Output:

```
Regn DocName
1    1
1    2.1
1    2.2
2    5.1
2    5.2
2    6
```

Comment: I'm sorry but could you please clarify your question a little? I'm not sure what you'd like to achieve. Maybe add some pseudo code?

Comment: @Dublicator, provide sample input and output for method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a default constructor for Foo try to use this:

```
var newItems = items.
            GroupBy(f => Tuple.Create(f.Regn, f.DocName)).
            SelectMany(gr => gr.Count()<=1 ? gr : gr.Select((f, i) => new Foo
            {
                Regn = f.Regn,
                DocName = f.DocName + "." + (i + 1)
            }));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can group with LINQ and cast out groups that only have one item, then iterate over the items in each group to set the `DocName`:

```
// Group and filter
var groups = items.GroupBy(i => new { i.Regn, i.DocName })
                  .Where(g => g.Count() > 1);

// Iterate over each group with many items
foreach (var g in groups) {
    var itemsInGroup = g.ToArray();
    // Iterate over the items and set DocName
    for (var i = 0; i < itemsInGroup.Length; ++i) {
        itemsInGroup[i].DocName = g.Key + "." + (i + 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All in one statement, just for fun.

```
var query = items.GroupBy(i => new { i.DocName, i.Regn })
    .SelectMany(group => 
        {
            int itemNum = 0;
            return group.Select(item =>
                {
                    var suffix = itemNum > 0 ? ("." + itemNum) : "";
                    var newDocName = item.DocName + suffix;
                    itemNum++;
                    return new { item, NewDocName = newDocName };
                });
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

Or use a LINQ statement to create a new result set like:

```
var fixedSet = from entry in existing
               group entry by entry.DocName + entry.Regn into groupedEntries
               let groupedEntriesAsArray = groupedEntries.ToArray()
               from groupedEntry in groupedEntriesAsArray
               let index = Array.IndexOf(groupedEntriesAsArray, groupedEntry)
               select new Foo
               {
                   DocName =
                       string.Format("{0}.{1}", groupedEntry.DocName, index + 1),
                   Regn =
                       string.Format("{0}.{1}", groupedEntry.Regn, index + 1)
               };
```

Comment: I'm not a downvoter but some problems in your code: 1. Is not readable, 2. instead of `Array.IndexOf(groupedEntriesAsArray, groupedEntry)` you can use `Select` with indexer, your current approach is not good when performance issue is important also it's depend on equality implementation of class, may be cause same values for different objet. I think MAKKAM answer is  best one in this case.

Comment: @Saeed Amiri: Thanks. I'm aware of the negative attributes using this approach, but i have to disagree on the readablity. I gave this example because no other answer introduced a query syntax like linq statement. The way i  read it, it makes perfect sence and is the most readable (compared to others). But ofcourse this is a personal taste

Comment: As you said it seems to be personal taste, but in all dot Notation prefered to query syntax in linq except in some cases see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/630045/linq-dot-notation-vs-query-expression for discussion about this.

Comment: @Polity, your code is readable enough, but I totally agree with Saeed about performance issues. Also I think it's not a good idea to group by concatenation of Regn and DocName. Check out foo1 = new Foo{Regn="c", DocName="ab"} and foo2 = new Foo{Regn="bc", DocName="a"}.  Your query will place both of them in one group.