# Linq to Sql join two tables

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have such database structure (1 - one, 0 - many)

```
Product 1->0 Orders 0->1 Users
```

I need to find all users for specified product, I have started writing linq query but don't know how to finish it.

```
public IQueryable<User> GetUsers(int productId)
{            
  return _db.Products.First(p => p.Id == productId)....
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First things first, the `First` method will only return the first item that meets your criteria, and since you want to return an `IQueryable` of `User`s, this is probably not what you want.

Second, I think the easiest way to get started with Linq-to-SQL is to use query notation, especially when you're dealing with joins, which [don't look too pretty when using lambda expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/630093/684271).

```
public IQueryable<User> GetUsers(int productId)
{
    return from p in _db.Products
           join o in _db.Orders on p.Id equals o.productId
           join u in _db.Users on o.userId equals u.userId
           where p.productId == productId
           select u;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work (written in VB.net):

```
Dim users() = (from x in _db.Users
             Join y in _db.Orders on y.userid equals x.userid
             Join z in _db.Product on z.productid equals y.productid
             where z.productname = "ProductName"
             select x.firstname,x.lastname,x.email,e.tel).toarray()
```

I've guessed at the fields in the tables, but this will give you the firstname, lastname email and telephone number of users that have ordered a certain product.

Thanks

Paul.