# Linq nested select new not working

Tags: linq, subsonic, subsonic3

I'm trying to get eager loading working with Subsonic, and it's been returning null for me.

In the method below, I'm trying to hydrate a domain model (UserModel) which contains another domain model (CompanyModel).  However, with the code below, UserModel.Company is always null.

What am I missing here.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
public IList<UserModel> GetUsers()
{             
    return (from u in SubsonicSqlServer.Users.All()
            select new UserModel
                       {
                           UserId= u.UserId,
                           Company = (from c in u.Companies
                                    select new CompanyModel
                                               {
                                                   CompanyId = c.CompanyId,
                                                   CompanyName = c.CompanyName
                                               }).SingleOrDefault(),
                           FirstName = u.FirstName,
                           LastName = u.LastName,
                           BirthDate = u.BirthDate
                       }).ToList();

}
```

Update (08/11/09):

More toying around with the code, I found out that setting CompanyId in the following example doesn't work either.  I initially thought this was an issue with Subsonic, but if the code below doesn't work, I'm guessing it has something to do with my Linq statement.  Any ideas?

```
public IList<UserModel> GetUsers()
{             
    return (from u in SubsonicSqlServer.Users.All()
            select new UserModel
                       {
                           UserId= u.UserId,                            
                           CompanyId = Guid.NewGuid(),
                           FirstName = u.FirstName,
                           LastName = u.LastName,
                           BirthDate = u.BirthDate
                       }).ToList();

}
```

Update (11/17/2009):

Still haven't found a solution.  But we are switching to nHibernate (not because of this issue).

Comment: According to this thread, there's issues with projection (selecting to a non-SubSonic type): http://groups.google.com/group/subsonicproject/browse_thread/thread/2b569539b7f67a34?hl=en&pli=1  It might be related to that.

Comment: which subsonic version that you're using?

Comment: @Funky812: Subsonic version 3.0.0.3

Comment: I've come across this same problem, tried Funky81's fork, but still ended up with projection issues. Do you have any recommendations on setting up using code from your fork?

Comment: toyed around with it some more, ended up returning everything, nested model data and all, into an anonymous object, then copying it over to the real object.

Answer (score 2):

"UserModel.Company is always null."

since you are setting this with an expression that ends with `.SingleOrDefault()`, I'm going to suggest that the query isn't returning a single item.  Start investigating there.  If you are expecting exactly one item in `u.Companies`, change to `.Single()` and force an early failure.

You can do the `.Single()` before creating the new `CompanyModel` object, I think.

As for style, I like the query comprehension syntax ("`from x in y select`") but find it awkward when combined with traditional dot-notation syntax.  It's just hard to read.  ([LINQ - Fluent and Query Expression - Is there any benefit(s) of one over other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214500/which-linq-syntax-do-you-prefer-fluent-or-query-expression/214610#214610)).

Consider using `let` in the query comprehension to make it clearer.

Also, since a query already returns an `IEnumerable<T>`, and calling `ToList()` forces all items to be realized, I would modify my method to return `IEnumerable<T>` if possible.

So, in your case, I would refactor the first to say:

```
public IEnumerable<User> GetUsers()
{ 
    return from u in SubsonicSqlServer.Users.All()
        let c = u.Companies.Single()
        select new UserModel
        {
            UserId = u.UserId,
            Company = new CompanyModel
            {
                CompanyId = c.CompanyId,
                CompanyName = c.CompanyName
            },
            FirstName = e.FirstName,
            LastName = e.LastName,
            BirthDate = e.BirthDate
        };
}
```

If it makes sense in your object model, you could modify `User` to have a constructor that takes whatever type `u` is, and it gets even simpler:

```
return from u in SubsonicSqlServer.Users.All()
    select new UserModel (u);
```

or even

```
return SubsonicSqlServer.Users.All().Select(u => new UserModel (u));
```

Comment: Jay, I implemented your suggestion and now I'm getting a Subsonic error: "Reference to undefined column". I'll continue to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

Two things

1. You're returning a `List<UserModel>` when your method's signature line says `IList<User>` does `UserModel` inherit from `User`?
2. Am I missing something, where does `e` come from?

> FirstName = e.FirstName,
>   LastName = e.LastName,
>   BirthDate = e.BirthDate Blockquote

Comment: wawa,

Regarding

1) My bad, the return signature should've been IList<UserModel>.  I will update the code in the original question

2) Again, my bad, e, should've been u. What I did was I copied the actual source code and turn it into something  I can share.  But it wasn't done carefully enough as it seems.  

Thanks for catching it.

Answer (score 0):

Please check out my fork @ github (http://github.com/funky81/SubSonic-3.0/commit/aa7a9c1b564b2667db7fbd41e09ab72f5d58dcdb)  for this solution, actually there's a problem when subsonic try to project new type class, so there's nothin wrong with your code actually :D