# Html Decode with Lambda Expression in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, linq-to-entities

I am trying to decode HTML in lambda expression but its giving following error:

"LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method '`System.String HtmlDecode(System.String)`' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

And I am using code as bellow:

```
OtherUserInformation userData = db.Users
    .Where(u => u.UserID.Equals(inputUserid))
    .Select(x => new OtherUserInformation
    {
        Address = x.location == null ? "" : x.location,

        UserPic = db.UserProfile
            .Where(u => u.UserID.Equals(x.UserID))
            .Select(y => y.profileImg)
            .FirstOrDefault() == null 
                ? profileImagePath + "140_profile_default.jpg" 
                : profileImagePath + "140_" + db.UserProfile
                    .Where(u => u.UserID.Equals(x.UserID))
                    .Select(y => y.profileImg)
                    .FirstOrDefault(),
        CoverPic = db.UserProfile
            .Where(u => u.UserID.Equals(x.UserID))
            .Select(y => y.CoverImg)
            .FirstOrDefault() == null 
                ? coverImagePath + "812_cover_default.jpg" 
                : coverImagePath + coverPicPrefix + db.UserProfile
                    .Where(u => u.UserID.Equals(x.UserID))
                    .Select(y => y.CoverImg)
                    .FirstOrDefault(),
        Detail = db.UserProfile
            .Where(u => u.UserID.Equals(x.UserID))
            .Select(y => y.About).FirstOrDefault() == null 
                ? "" 
                : WebUtility.HtmlDecode(db.UserProfile
                    .Where(u => u.UserID.Equals(x.UserID))
                    .AsEnumerable()
                    .Select(y => y.About)
                    .FirstOrDefault()),
        FollowerCount = db.FollowUser
            .Where(u => u.FriendId.Equals(x.UserID) && u.FollowStatus.Equals(1))
            .Count(),
        Name = x.FirstName + " " + x.LastName,
        IsFollow = db.FollowUser
            .Where(u => u.UserId.Equals(userAuthInfo.UserId) 
                && u.FriendId.Equals(inputUserid) 
                && u.FollowStatus.Equals(1))
            .Select(z => z)
            .FirstOrDefault() == null ? "False" : "True",
    })
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

In above code, I need "Detail" field which have HTML encoded data. But I am not able to decode html in lambda expression.
Any help would be highly appreciate.

Comment: This has been asked so many times in so many different flavours.

Comment: I tried but I didn't get any satisfactory answer of my question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Method cannot be translated into a store expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3846716/method-cannot-be-translated-into-a-store-expression)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got solution for this and added few line of code at the bottom of above query as bellow:

}).FirstOrDefault().AsEnumerable().Select(x => new OtherUserInformation
                        {

```
                        Address = x.Address,
                        UserPic = x.UserPic,
                        CoverPic = x.CoverPic,
                        Detail = Regex.Replace(x.Detail, "<.*?>", string.Empty),
                        FollowerCount = x.FollowerCount,
                        Name = x.Name,
                        IsFollow = x.IsFollow,
                        Categories = x.Categories,
                        Followers = x.Followers

                    }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Above solution worked for me. Happy coding :)

Comment: We just need to add AsEnumerable() and then select all fields from above query. I am using Regex.Replace function here, but we can use HttpUtility.HtmlDecode function also. For now I just removed all HTML tags as per my requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use that method, or any like it, before you have resolved your query because sql doesn't know anything about that assembly.  If it's not an EntityFunction then you have to reproject the list after resolution.  If you use a data mapper like AutoMapper you can just use that in the reprojection and make the call there but if you need to do it by hand do it after you call toList().

```
        db.Users.Select(x=>new YourObject{//data})
        .ToList()
    .Select(x=>new YourObject{
       //now you can use whatever methods you want from whatever assemblies you want
       SomePropertyValue = x.SomePropertyValue,
       SomeOtherValue = SomeAssembly.SomeMethod(x.SomeOtherValue)
});
```

Comment: The only drawback is that his projection seem to make heavy use of the database. By enumeating first, the projection will probably produce quite a lot of additional database queries.

Comment: not true, there are no additional database calls.  Once the list is resolved from the database doing another projection is done in memory from one object to the other.

Answer (score 0):

Try the HttpUtility.HtmlDecode Method instead

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.htmldecode(v=vs.110).aspx

Or try the decoding the field inside the Select method as per the example below:

```
OtherUserInformation userData = db.Users.Where(u => u.UserID.Equals(inputUserid)).Select(x => new OtherUserInformation
                    {
                        Address = x.location == null ? "" : x.location,
                       // UserPic = Utilities.ImagePathForProfileForUserByDiviceType(db.UserProfile.Where(u => u.UserID.Equals(x.UserID)).Select(y => y.profileImg).FirstOrDefault(),deviceType),
                       // CoverPic = Utilities.ImagePathForCoverImageForUserByDiviceType(db.UserProfile.Where(u => u.UserID.Equals(x.UserID)).Select(y => y.CoverImg).FirstOrDefault(), deviceType),

                        UserPic = db.UserProfile.Where(u => u.UserID.Equals(x.UserID)).Select(y => y.profileImg).FirstOrDefault() == null ? profileImagePath + "140_profile_default.jpg" : profileImagePath + "140_" + db.UserProfile.Where(u => u.UserID.Equals(x.UserID)).Select(y => y.profileImg).FirstOrDefault(),
                        CoverPic = db.UserProfile.Where(u => u.UserID.Equals(x.UserID)).Select(y => y.CoverImg).FirstOrDefault() == null ? coverImagePath + "812_cover_default.jpg" : coverImagePath + coverPicPrefix + db.UserProfile.Where(u => u.UserID.Equals(x.UserID)).Select(y => y.CoverImg).FirstOrDefault(),
                        Detail = db.UserProfile.Where(u => u.UserID.Equals(x.UserID)).Select(y => y.About).FirstOrDefault() == null ? "" : db.UserProfile.Where(u => u.UserID.Equals(x.UserID)).AsEnumerable().Select(y => WebUtility.HtmlDecode(y.About)).FirstOrDefault(),
                        FollowerCount = db.FollowUser.Where(u => u.FriendId.Equals(x.UserID) && u.FollowStatus.Equals(1)).Count(),
                        Name = x.FirstName + " " + x.LastName,
                        IsFollow = db.FollowUser.Where(u => u.UserId.Equals(userAuthInfo.UserId) && u.FriendId.Equals(inputUserid) && u.FollowStatus.Equals(1)).Select(z => z).FirstOrDefault() == null ? "False" : "True",


                        })


                    }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: No, that is not the issue.