# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 ToInt32(Boolean)'

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework

So basically, I am trying to return a set of values to a GridView, which doesn't meet any of the values within an array. However, upon attempting I am getting the error of

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 ToInt32(Boolean)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Here is my code:

```
        public List<Room> getAvailRoom()
    {
        //Sessions from Default Page
        DateTime checkedIn = Convert.ToDateTime(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["checkIn"]);
        DateTime checkedOut = Convert.ToDateTime(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["checkOut"]);

        //retrieves all the bookings which happen between two dates
        var booking = (from b in context.Booking
                         where b.departureDate >= checkedIn && b.arrivalDate <= checkedOut
                         select b);

        //Counts how many rooms are booked during those dates
        int countRooms = booking.Count();

        int[] bookings = new int[countRooms];
        foreach (var booktypes in booking)
        {

                for (int i = 0; i < countRooms; i++)
                {
                    //Addings the RoomIds to the array
                    bookings[i] = booktypes.RoomId;
                }

        }
        //Returns values that does not equal to any roomIds within the bookings array.
        return (from b in context.Room
                where b.roomId != Convert.ToInt32(bookings.Any())
                select b).ToList();
    }
```

Any ideas what I am doing incorrectly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Method cannot be translated into a store expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3846716/method-cannot-be-translated-into-a-store-expression)

Comment: It's worth explaining why this happens. LINQ on in-memory objects (`IEnumerable<T>`) can handle any valid C# expression, because the lambda is compiled by the C# compiler and invoked simply by invoking the delegate. Other LINQ providers (operating on `IQueryable<T>`, for example) have to translate your lambdas to something else (SQL queries, for example). Since not all valid C# expressions can be translated to something else (SQL is very limited compared to C#), such providers can only handle very specific kinds of expressions. So, you've found an expression that your provider can't handle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really were looking for a `Contains` query I think:

```
 return (from b in context.Room
                where !bookings.Contains(b.roomId) 
                select b).ToList();
```

Two problems with your snippet:

- `Any()` returns a boolean - that's not at all what you want
- You are trying to execute `Convert.ToInt32` in SQL realm - there's no
  equivalent to this there (basically Linq to Entities cannot convert this part to a SQL query), so this can't work.

Answer (score 0):

Note: "bookings.Any()" will return a true or false indicating whether there is any element in the booking array. You are getting this error because you are trying to convert a boolean which is the result of the expression "bookings.Any()" to an integer.

If what you want to do is to get all rooms not booked then i will recommend

```
      if(bookings.Any()){
       return (from b in context.Room
            where !bookings.contains(b.roomId)  
            select b).ToList();
       }else{

       return (from b in context.Room  
            select b).ToList();
      }
```

meaning: if we have any room booked select those room that are not booked else select all the rooms(since no room is booked)

Note: Pls do your conversion outside link and use your result in your link statement if you need to do type conversion. Since this is C# i don't see you having any issue with type conversion here. 
your "bookings[i] = booktypes.RoomId;" should return an array of int which require no conversion i.e "Convert.ToInt32" but if need be for this conversion do it before you i.e

```
    if(bookings.Any()){
       var thebooking = new List<int>();
     foreach (var booking in bookings)
    {
       thebooking.Add(Convert.ToInt32(booking));
     }

       return (from b in context.Room
            where !thebooking.contains(b.roomId)  
            select b).ToList();
       }else{

       return (from b in context.Room  
            select b).ToList();
      }
```

Comment: I can't understand the meaning of `Convert.ToInt32(bookings.Any())`. What does it mean?