# Can't translate method into a store expression

Tags: c#, linq

The closest to my questions that I've found is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3846716/method-cannot-be-translated-into-a-store-expression) and as far I can see, it's not regarding the same issue. I might be mistaken, in which case, I hope someone can explain how the similarity goes (except for the same words referring to the error, that is). With that being said, I have the following issue.

This works as supposed to.

```
List<Typo> things = context.Things.Where(thing => thing.Nice).ToList();
```

This, however, doesn't.

```
List<Typo> things = context.Things.Where(thing => IsNice(thing)).ToList();
...
private bool IsNice(Typo thing) { return thing.Nice; }
```

*context* is of type *ModelContainer* deriving *DbContext*. I've been told that it's a standard setup for EF and I have no reason to suspect otherwise. The error message claims the following.

> {"LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method XXX method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."}

I have no experience with this error and, frankly, the research I've made gave me very little clarity. What can I look into to (a) make it work **my way** and (b) investigate it further.

Comment: There are dozens of 'cannot be translated into a store expression' questions already posted, see the Related column on the right. They're all about the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

IMO, it's still the same issue as the question you mention: LINQ to Entities cannot interpret `IsNice`, and thus, you need 'normal' LINQ to resolve the Where method. You can force this with the `AsEnumberable` method:

```
List<Typo> things = context.Things.AsEnumerable().Where(thing => IsNice(thing)).ToList();
```

Or even shorter.

```
List<Typo> things = context.Things.Where(IsNice).ToList();
```

Comment: Ha, that's (a). And so well put that (b) won't be necessary, hence calling for a +1. Still a bit weird that I can put expression into the *Where* clause but I can't put a method with that expression into it...

Comment: Is that because the method is declared in the class that isn't *Thing*? Or would *thing.Nice()* also produce the error?

Comment: @KonradViltersten A simple lambda can be decomposed into an expression tree.  A method call cannot.  It may be _possible_ for the compiler to dig into the method code, decompile it, and create an expression tree, but the same limitations would exist and require that the method be so simple that 99.9% of methods couldn't be decomposed.

Comment: No, it is because LINQ to Entities can't make a SQL statement out of the method you provide to `Where` (it can't look 'inside' the method, so to speak).

Comment: @HenkHolterman Technically, using `AsEnumerable()` just changes the query provider from EF to Linq-to-Objects.  It still does not execute the query until it is enumerated.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use your own method in a lambda expression of Linq to Entities, even if it only encapsulates your entities properties because Linq to Entities doesn't know how to translate them into a valid SQL statement.

For getting your methods working you must get the entities from the database with a valid LinQ to Entities query and fill with them a C# collection (like a List). You can use the *extension methods* .AsEnumerable(), .ToList(), Select(), ...

Here you have a list of .NET methods that LinQ to Entities can translate and you can use in your lambda expression, also with a brief explanation of your exception:

[CLR Method to Canonical Function Mapping](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738681(v=vs.100).aspx)

And here you have a list with the LinQ methods supported by LinQ to Entities:

[Supported LinQ methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738550(v=vs.100).aspx)