# Projection of single entities in EF with extension methods

Tags: c#, entity-framework, expression-trees

I like to do projection from my entity models into my view models using extension methods. This means I dont over/under fetch for my models and it makes the code nice and readable. It makes sense that sometimes the projections may include nested models, and I want to get reuse on those sub-projections.

I want to be able to do something like the following:

```
ctx.People.FiltersAndThings().ToViewModels();//the project my DB Models into view models
```

Extension methods for actual projection

```
public static IQueryable<PersonModel> ToViewModels(this IQueryable<Person> entities)
{
    return entities.Select(x => new PersonModel {
        Me = x.Me.ToViewModel(), //this method cannot be translated into a store expression
        Friends = x.Friends.AsQueryable().ToViewModels() //works fine with some magic (tm)
    });
}

public static IQueryable<ProfileModel> ToViewModels(this IQueryable<Profile> entities)
{
    return entities.Select(x => new ProfileModel { Name = x.Name });
}


public static ProfileModel ToViewModel(this Profile entity)
{
    return new ProfileModel { Name = entity.Name };
}
```

When using a Queryable (eg `Friends = x.Friends.AsQueryable().ToViewModels()`) we can use some magic to flatten this to an expression (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/10726256/1070291, answer by @LordTerabyte) But when we are doing an assignment with a new clause (eg `Me = new ProfileModel { Name = x.Me.Name }`) its not an expression so if we bundle this under an extension method (eg `Me = x.Me.ToViewModel()`) we can't flatten this to an expression.

**How does an assignment to a new object work under the scenes in EF?**

**Is there a way to do convertion to a new object via an extension method?**

Full demo code here: https://github.com/lukemcgregor/ExtensionMethodProjection

**Edit:**

I now have a blog post ([Composable Repositories - Nesting Extensions](http://blog.staticvoid.co.nz/2016/10/24/composable_repositories_-_nesting_extensions)) and [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/LinqExpander/) to help with nesting extension methods in linq

Comment: Does it work with your current code?

Comment: `Me = x.Me.ToViewModel()` doesnt work, if you would like a demo app of the rest working I can post to GH

Comment: Actually it would help to see your `Person` model and `PersonModel`, not the full code, but the relevant parts.

Comment: A bit far-fetched, but does this work: `Me = x.Friends.AsQueryable().ToViewModels().Where(n => n.Name = x.Me.Name).Single()`

Comment: Full working code in a console app here: https://github.com/lukemcgregor/ExtensionMethodProjection

Comment: @KeyurPATEL yes `Me = x.Friends.AsQueryable().ToViewModels().Where(n => n.Name == x.Me.Name).FirstOrDefault()` that would run but it doesnt really solve the problem. I could probably even rewite the code to use the reverse nav properties and a where clause but it make my code complex and less readable. I also couldnt hide this behind a helper

Comment: Take a look at these: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3850254/6741868 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/31464364/6741868. They suggest that linq won't allow methods unless you force it behind `.AsEnumerable()` or `.AsQueryable()` in your case.

Comment: @KeyurPATEL yeah thats definitally the case, this question is about how i would go about unwrapping an extension method onto the existing queryable. Its really about how the underlying expression visitor works in relation to an assignment such as `Me = new ProfileModel { Name = x.Me.Name }`

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood your question then. Hope somebody can answer this one for you, requires deep understanding.

Comment: @KeyurPATEL yeah its pretty niche, it requires an understanding of how expression trees are working in relation to an assignment like this

Comment: Doesn't seem like you are taking advantage of an IQueryable anyway, so why not just use IEnumerable?

Comment: @Shoe in real lifes, my projections get much more complex. This is a way of not over/underfetching. If i were to do this in an enumerable I would also need to know the include chains each projection required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29448432/pass-expression-parameter-as-argument-to-another-expression/29471092#29471092). It does a very similar thing what you want. Basically you would define your transformation as an Expression tree, e.g:

```
public static Expression<Func<Profile, ProfileModel>> ToProfileViewModel()
{
    return entity => new ProfileModel { Name = entity.Name };
}
```

And then do invocations of this (e.g. ExpressionsHelper.ToProfileViewModel().AsQuote()(p)).

If you prefer, you can modify the visitors, to allow a nicer syntax. Something along the lines:

```
[ReplacementInExpressionTrees(MethodName=nameof(ExpressionsHelper.ToProfileViewModel))]
public static ProfileModel ToViewModel(this Profile profile)
{
    // this implementation is only here, so that if you call the method in a non expression tree, it will still work
    return ExpressionsHelper.ToProfileViewModel().Compile()(profile); // tip: cache the compiled func!
```

Now you need to create a visitor, that checks all method calls, and when finds a method with this attribute, it changes the whole call to ExpressionsHelper.ToProfileViewModel().AsQuote()(profile). This is as an exercise for you :)
    }

Comment: you could also directly convert on such constructs to the desired target expression

Comment: This looks awesome, you referred to `ReplacementInExpressionTreesAttribute`, what would this look like? I assume this is something I would need to write? It looks like this is supposed to replace the method call with the expression listed when used in a tree. This is exactly what im after :)

Comment: Ok ive built something that does this replacement, I had to put it into my existing visitor rather than using a new one like `MultiParamReplaceVisitor`. It works for doing that replacement but it breaks if there are any other extension methods under the replaced lambda. I think this is probably out of the scope of this question so I will ask another. Code of what I actually did here: https://github.com/lukemcgregor/ExtensionMethodProjection/blob/master/ExtensionMethodProjection/Expandable.cs

Comment: Have asked new question about my specific bug here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39864270/expression-visitor-only-calling-visitparameter-for-some-lambda-expressions would appreciate if you had any ideas.