# Expression visitor only calling VisitParameter for some lambda expressions

Tags: c#, lambda, expression-trees

I want to be able to used nested extension methods to do projection of entities in EF to corresponding view models. (see my previous question [Projection of single entities in EF with extension methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39585427/projection-of-single-entities-in-ef-with-extension-methods) for more details on what im doing).

As per this question I built an attribute to replace an extension method in an expression tree with a lambda to be able to do this. It takes the method arguments from the extentsion method and replaces them on as VisitParameter is called (I dont know if there is a way to replace the parameters inline in the LambdaExpression).

This works well for something like this:

```
entity => new ProfileModel
{
    Name = entity.Name  
}
```

And I can see the expression visitor replace the entity parameter on the LambdaExpression to the correct one from the extension method args.

However when I change it to something more nested say,

```
entity => new ProfileModel
{
    SomethingElses = entity.SomethingElses.AsQueryable().ToViewModels()
}
```

then I get:

> The parameter 'entity' was not bound in the specified LINQ to Entities query expression.

Additionally `VisitParameter` in my expression visitor doesn't seem to get called at all with the parameter 'entity'.

Its like its not using my visitor at all for the second Lambda, but I dont know why It would for one and not the other?

**How can I correctly replace the parameter in the case of both types of lambda expressions?**

My Visitor below:

```
    protected override Expression VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node)
    {
        bool expandNode = node.Method.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ExpandableMethodAttribute), false).Any();
        if (expandNode && node.Method.IsStatic)
        {
            object[] args = new object[node.Arguments.Count];
            args[0] = _provider.CreateQuery(node.Arguments[0]);

            for (int i = 1; i < node.Arguments.Count; i++)
            {
                Expression arg = node.Arguments[i];
                args[i] = (arg.NodeType == ExpressionType.Constant) ? ((ConstantExpression)arg).Value : arg;
            }
            return ((IQueryable)node.Method.Invoke(null, args)).Expression;
        }
        var replaceNodeAttributes = node.Method.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ReplaceInExpressionTree), false).Cast<ReplaceInExpressionTree>();
        if (replaceNodeAttributes.Any() && node.Method.IsStatic)
        {
            var replaceWith = node.Method.DeclaringType.GetMethod(replaceNodeAttributes.First().MethodName).Invoke(null, null);
            if (replaceWith is LambdaExpression)
            {
                RegisterReplacementParameters(node.Arguments.ToArray(), replaceWith as LambdaExpression);
                return Visit((replaceWith as LambdaExpression).Body);
            }
        }
        return base.VisitMethodCall(node);
    }
    protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
    {
        Expression replacement;
        if (_replacements.TryGetValue(node, out replacement))
            return Visit(replacement);
        return base.VisitParameter(node);
    }
    private void RegisterReplacementParameters(Expression[] parameterValues, LambdaExpression expressionToVisit)
    {
        if (parameterValues.Length != expressionToVisit.Parameters.Count)
            throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("The parameter values count ({0}) does not match the expression parameter count ({1})", parameterValues.Length, expressionToVisit.Parameters.Count));
        foreach (var x in expressionToVisit.Parameters.Select((p, idx) => new { Index = idx, Parameter = p }))
        {
            if (_replacements.ContainsKey(x.Parameter))
            {
                throw new Exception("Parameter already registered, this shouldn't happen.");
            }
            _replacements.Add(x.Parameter, parameterValues[x.Index]);
        }
    }
```

Full repro code example here: https://github.com/lukemcgregor/ExtensionMethodProjection

**Edit:**

I now have a blog post ([Composable Repositories - Nesting Extensions](http://blog.staticvoid.co.nz/2016/10/24/composable_repositories_-_nesting_extensions)) and [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/LinqExpander/) to help with nesting extension methods in linq

Comment: Because `ToViewModels` will have `expandNode` true, causing you to return a new expression which will be traversed, essentially discarding you r original expression. Remember that you'll be parsing ToViewModels -> AsQueryable -> SomethingElses -> entity.

Comment: @rob not sure what you mean about expandNode true? What is that and how does it work? Can I get around this and keep using this expression?

Comment: @downvoter care to comment on why you feel this is a poor question?

Comment: In `VisitMethodCall`, you've got a flag `expandNode` based on the attributes (which `ToViewModels` is marked with). When `expandNode` is set to true (and static), it eventually returns `((IQueryable)node.Method.Invoke(null, args)).Expression`. This is a new expression which likely does not contain the original parameter expression. I'm not able to run your full code (at work), but at a glance, it's very likely this is the cause of you not seeing `VisitParameter` execute on the second example

Comment: Oh right sorry i thought you were talking about some expression tree arguement. Is that because the Invoke will create a brand new expression? I wrapped it in a `Visit()` and now everything works, thanks.

Comment: @rob If you put that as an answer ill mark it :)

Comment: Just for my understanding calling Visit will make the current visitor process that expression rather than creating a new visitor to do it?

Comment: Without Visit() you're essentially stopping the traversal of the tree. The method becomes a 'leaf' node (even though the result may be a tree itself). Wrapping it in Visit allows your visitor code to also execute on the new expression

Comment: I think there is a big confusion here. Your visitor does NOT need any provider reference. You do not care abou the provider, should NEVER call provider createquery, and usually invoke is also a smell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing to remember is that when parsing nodes, we essentially run backwards:

```
entity => new ProfileModel
{
    SomethingElses = entity.SomethingElses.AsQueryable().ToViewModels()
}
```

Here, we process `ToViewModels()`, then `AsQueryable()`, then `SomethingElses`, and finally `entity`. Since we're finding that `entity` is never parsed (`VisitParameter`), it means something in our chain stopped the traversal of the tree.

We have two culprits here:

`VisitMethodCall()` (AsQueryable and ToViewModels) and `VisitMemberAccess()` (SomethingElses)

We're not overriding `VisitMemberAccess`, so the problem must lie within `VisitMethodCall`

We have three exit points for that method:

```
return ((IQueryable)node.Method.Invoke(null, args)).Expression;

return Visit((replaceWith as LambdaExpression).Body);

return base.VisitMethodCall(node);
```

The first line returns an expression verbatim, and stops further traversal of the tree. This means descendant nodes will never be visited - as we're saying the work is essentially done. Whether or not this is correct behavior really depends on what you're wanting to achieve with the visitor.

Changing the code to

```
return Visit(((IQueryable)node.Method.Invoke(null, args)).Expression);
```

Means we traverse this (potentially new!) expression. This doesn't guarantee we'll visit the correct nodes (for example, this expression may be completely independent of the original) - but it *does* mean that if this new expression contained a parameter expression, that the parameter expression would be visited properly.

Comment: Awesome thanks heaps for the help ive been trying to work this out for days :) Im really just learing how Expression trees even work.

Comment: @LukeMcGregor Not a problem mate :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you overcomplicated it. See the visitor:

```
public class CustomerVM { }
public class Customer {}

public class ReplaceMethodAttribute: Attribute
{
    public string ReplacementMethodName {get; private set;}
    public ReplaceMethodAttribute(string name)
    {
        ReplacementMethodName = name;
    }
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static CustomerVM ToCustomerVM(Customer customer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    [ReplaceMethod("Extensions.ToCustomerVM")]
    public static CustomerVM ToVM(this Customer customer)
    {
        return Extensions.ToCustomerVM(customer);
    }
}

public class ReplaceMethodVisitor: ExpressionVisitor
{
    protected override Expression VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression exp)
    {
        var attr = exp.Method.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ReplaceMethodAttribute), true).OfType<ReplaceMethodAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
        if (attr != null)
        {
            var parameterTypes = exp.Method.GetParameters().Select(i => i.ParameterType).ToArray();
            var mi = GetMethodInfo(attr.ReplacementMethodName, parameterTypes);
            return Visit(Expression.Call(mi, exp.Arguments));
        }
        return base.VisitMethodCall(exp);
    }

    private MethodInfo GetMethodInfo(string name, Type[] argumentTypes)
    {
        // enhance with input checking
        var lastDot = name.LastIndexOf('.');
        var type = name.Substring(0, lastDot);
        var methodName = name.Substring(lastDot);
        return this.GetType().Assembly.GetTypes().Single(x => x.FullName == type).GetMethod(methodName, argumentTypes); // this might need adjusting if types are in different assembly
    }

}
```

Comment: The OP doesn't want to replace the method call with another method call (the method that the attribute references), he wants to replace the method call with the expression **returned** by the method referenced by the attribute.