# Convert 'string' to 'int' in an .Any() LINQ query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, sql-server-2012, entity-framework-6

I have a conditional statement that evaluates an `.Any()` LINQ query against my DB.

It is throwing an error when casting/converting a string to long value.

```
(long.TryParse(m.Reference,out t)? t : long.MaxValue)
```

The error is something like:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method '....' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression

Am I doing something wrong here? How can I achieve this?

```
using (var ctx = new DatabaseEntities())
{
    long t;
    if(!ctx.CustomerInboxes.Any(m=>m.CustomerId == customerId
        && m.Reference == item.ShoppingCartWebId.ToString() 
        && m.SubjectId == HerdbookConstants.PendingCartMessage 
        && item.ShoppingCartWebId > (long.TryParse(m.Reference,out t)? t : long.MaxValue)))
    )){
        // do something special
    }
}
```

Comment: did you try adding one condition at a time to rule out it is not problem with any of those 4 conditions?

Comment: yes, all custom convertions can't be translated to SQL

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti I cant evaluate as >  or < as strings.

Comment: @Igor but this is not what I am trying to achieve. I need to determine if the m.Reference is greater or less than the item.ShoppingCartWebId. The m.Reference is stored a string(out of my control), even though in this scenario it is always of type  long.

Comment: Are you using EntityFramework? if yes then which version?

Comment: Even if it worked, wondering how `m.Reference == item.ShoppingCartWebId.ToString() ` and `item.ShoppingCartWebId > (long.TryParse(m.Reference,out t)? t : long.MaxValue)` be true at the same time.

Comment: @Igor String comparison is not the same as numeric comparison - for instance "2" > "11"

Comment: @IvanStoev, you are right, the logic is not correct. I will correct this.

Comment: @IvanStoev - good point. What about padding the left side of the smaller string with `0`? Only I can't find if `PadLeft` is supported in Linq to Sql.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Method cannot be translated into a store expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3846716/method-cannot-be-translated-into-a-store-expression)

Comment: @Igor That's an option. However there is no general canonical function for padding (in `DbFunctions`), only for SqlServer (in `SqlFunctions`).

Comment: @Mark - what store are you using? (Sql server or something else?)

Comment: @Igor SQLServer2012 EntityFramework 6

Comment: Does Convert.ToInt32(m.Reference) work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your code you when `m.Reference` is not a valid number the condition should fail, this can be done using `SqlFunctions.IsNumeric()`.

To compare numbers you can use `string.Compare` and simulate numeric comparison padding left with `0`s (it's possible with `SqlFunctions.Replicate()`).

It's not too pretty, but should works:

```
var itemId = item.ShoppingCartWebId.ToString();

ctx.CustomerInboxes.Any(m => ...
                          && SqlFunctions.IsNumeric(m.Reference) != 0 
                          && string.Compare(SqlFunctions.Replicate("0", m.Reference.Length > itemId.Length ? m.Reference.Length - itemId.Length : 0) + itemId, m.Reference) > 0);
```

However you always can switch to *Linq to Objects* to check this specific part:

```
ctx.CustomerInboxes.Where(m => m.CustomerId == customerId &&
                               m.Reference == item.ShoppingCartWebId.ToString()  &&
                               m.SubjectId == HerdbookConstants.PendingCartMessage)
                    .AsEnumerable()
                    .Any(c => item.ShoppingCartWebId > (long.TryParse(c.Reference, out t) ? t : long.MaxValue))
```

Comment: Thank you @Arturo, the first example seems to be working.

Answer (score 1):

A combination of a length check with string.Compare should do the trick.

### Logic

- if item.Reference.Length is greater in length it is also a larger number.
- If they are the same length then execute a `string.Compare` which evals from left to right which also works great for numbers.

`string.Compare(string a, string b)`. This returns:

- 1 if `a` is bigger than `b`
- 0 if `a` equals `b`
- -1 if `b` is bigger than `a`

### Code:

```
using (var ctx = new DatabaseEntities())
{
    var webId = item.ShoppingCartWebId.ToString();
    var webIdLength = webId.Length;

    if (!ctx.CustomerInboxes.Any(m => m.CustomerId == customerId
        && m.Reference == item.ShoppingCartWebId.ToString()
        && m.SubjectId == HerdbookConstants.PendingCartMessage
        && (m.Reference.Length > webIdLength || (m.Reference.Length == webIdLength && string.Compare(m.Reference, webId) > 0))))) {
            //do something special
        }
}
```

### Benefit

Indexes! Because there is no padding involved here the actual comparison check can still benefit from using any indexes on this column. If your data grows it should not impact performance too much. Unfortunately the length comparison will not utilize any indexes I believe but the comparison but this will *probably* have a smaller impact on performance than other parts of the query

### Assumptions

- There are no formatting characters like `,` or `.`
- There are no instances where strings are padded with `0` or spaces
- You are always comparing whole numbers (no fractions)

Answer (score 1):

```
using (var ctx = new DatabaseEntities())
{
    long t;
    if(!ctx.CustomerInboxes.ToList().Any(m=>m.CustomerId == customerId
        && m.Reference == item.ShoppingCartWebId.ToString() 
        && m.SubjectId == HerdbookConstants.PendingCartMessage 
        && item.ShoppingCartWebId > (long.TryParse(m.Reference,out t)? t : long.MaxValue)))
    ))
    {
        // do something special
    }
}
```

Just add `.ToList()`. While this will bring back your entire list to the client it will allow you to do the custom operators you want to do.

Based on the comments here is another alternative of bringing back a subset from the db then doing the custom parsing operator.

```
long t;
var initialQuery = ctx.CustomerInboxes.Where(x => m.CustomerId == customerId
    && m.Reference == item.ShoppingCartWebId.ToString()
    && m.SubjectId == HerdbookConstants.PendingCartMessage).ToList();

if (!initialQuery.Any(m => item.ShoppingCartWebId > (long.TryParse(m.Reference, out t) ? t : long.MaxValue)))
{
    // do something special
}
```

Comment: this will get all `CustomerInboxes` read from database into memory. Think about millions of records in the DB...

Comment: How is this a good answer, you don't even explain what you did different.  Arbitrarily calling ToList() will have alot of negative effect for massive tables

Comment: @trailmax While it will bring back all the records there are no requirements on performance etc etc. In addition, there is no indication that there is millions of records.

Comment: @johnny5 You are absolutely correct. However, the question does not state any requirements about performance, or the size of these arbitrary tables. Calling .ToList() will allow the user to achieve their goal by switching from Linq to Entities to Linq to Objects

Comment: @IdahoSixString , there are currently ~1million records and will grow.

Comment: @Mark Then I would suggest rewriting the query all together.

Comment: @IdahoSixString yeah I saw you change your answer so I corrected my vote

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to add a computed column in `CustomerInboxes` source table (I assumed it is a table, but it can be a view or a stored procedure), so that you do not have to make the ugly comparison that cannot be translated by LINQ2SQL:

```
ReferenceAsLong AS ISNULL(TRY_CONVERT(BIGINT, Reference), CAST(9223372036854775807 AS BIGINT)) PERSISTED
```

You troubling LINQ condition is simplified and should work correctly:

```
item.ShoppingCartWebId > ReferenceAsLong
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try using Convert.ToInt64 instead of long.TryParse.

Answer (score 0):

This Query will look horrible.  Ideally you should be switching this in the DB to be an int field.

(as long as there is no prepended 0s)
You can modify the logic so that if the length of ShoppingCartWebId is longer than the condition is met, alternatively if the length are equal a string compare should work fine

```
using (var ctx = new DatabaseEntities())
{
   long t;
  if(!ctx.CustomerInboxes.Any(m=>m.CustomerId == customerId
   && m.Reference == item.ShoppingCartWebId.ToString() 
   && m.SubjectId == HerdbookConstants.PendingCartMessage 
   && (item.ShoppingCartWebId.length > SqlFunctions.StringConvert((long).Reference) 
   || (item.ShoppingCartWebId.length == SqlFunctions.StringConvert((long).Reference
       && item.ShoppingCartWebId > SqlFunctions.StringConvert((long)m.Reference)
 ))){
     //do something special
   }
}
```