# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean Exists(System.Predicate`1[Entities.Connection])' method

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I tried to create list of notes that satisfying either of two conditions.
1. Matched with the created user.
2. OR Linked with the connections.

using the below code returns an exception. I know this exception is common for Linq to entitites expression. But my question is what is the alternative methods can be used instead of Exists?

"LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean Exists(System.Predicate`1[Entities.Connection])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

```
_context.Notes
        .Include(t => t.Connections)
        .Where(t => t.CreatedUserId == userId || t.Connections.ToList().Exists(c => c.UserId == userId))
```

Comment: Did you try searching for your error? There are any number of [duplicates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3846716/method-cannot-be-translated-into-a-store-expression) that will give you the answer.

Comment: Yeah, this is a very common error message here in SO. Anyway, the error message is clear, linq to entities does not suport exist, you should try to use Any() or Contains().

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue here is that Entity Framework does not understand your C# code and cannot parse .Exists().

An alternative way of writing this would be as followed:

```
_context.Notes
    .Include(t => t.Connections)
    .Where(t => t.CreatedUserId == userId || t.Connections.Any(c => c.UserId == userId));
```

Here the .Any() will return true if any Connections have a UserId that is equal to userId.