# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method - Entity Framework and DDD

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, domain-driven-design

I started using Entity Framework 6 and learning Domain Driven Design.

To my understanding, according to DDD principles, business logic should reside in the domain layer, in entities and value objects.

In my `ApplicationUser` class, I want to have a method that says whether or not the user is currently active in the chat:

```
public bool IsActiveInChat()
{
    return this.ConnectedToChat &&
       (DateTime.Now - this.LastChatActivity).TotalMinutes < 10;
}
```

The purpose of the method is to filter which users to display in the chat members list.

This is the query in `ApplicationUserManager`, which is the `Repository`:

```
public List<ApplicationUser> GetUsersConnectedToChat()
{
    List<ApplicationUser> users = Users
        .Where(u => u.IsActiveInChat())
        .ToList();

    return users;
}
```

When I run this code, I get the error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean
>   IsActiveInChat()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a
>   store expression.

I can easily make this work by transferring the logic into the `Repository`, but from what I read about DDD, the business logic should belong in the entities and not in the repositories.

This is a working version of the same query (without the method in `ApplicationUser`):

```
public List<ApplicationUser> GetUsersConnectedToChat()
{
    List<ApplicationUser> users = Users
        .Where(u => u.ConnectedToChat &&
            DbFunctions.DiffSeconds(DateTime.Now, u.LastChatActivity) < 10)
        .ToList();

    return users;
}
```

So, my question: is this a known issue with Entity Framework?

Am I misunderstanding something?

Is there a way to bypass this issue and keep the business logic inside the `User` entity?

P.S. - The question brought up by marc_s doesn't answer my question. Firstly, the answer given there suggests using `AsEnumerable`, which fetches the entire table into memory and is bad performance wise. It also doesn't answer my question of what is the Domain Driven Design approach to this issue, which appears to be quite common and something I would encounter a lot in my project.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Method cannot be translated into a store expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3846716/method-cannot-be-translated-into-a-store-expression)

Comment: I edited my question to explain why this is not a duplicate.

Comment: It is, because it answers your first question. And the other questions are too broad, because they would first need to discuss the false assumption that the EF class model is a domain model. It's a DAL.

Comment: If it helps, you can apply the AsEnumerable operator in the middle of the call chain. Everything before it will be translated to SQL and run on the db server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a common problem.

If your filtering logic is stored in C# functions, then the sql server does not know anything about it.

You have three options.

1. Pull all the data down from SQL and perform your filtering locally
   (which,as you point out, can lead to bad performance).
2. Move your filtering logic to SQL
3. Attempt to write your filtering
   logic in a manner that can be passed to and understood by sql.

By 3, I mean you can re-write your IsActiveInChat function like

```
Expression<Func<ApplicationUser, bool>> IsActiveInChat = r => 
     (r.ConnectedToChat.Value && (DateTime.Now - r.LastChatActivity).TotalMinutes < 10);
```

or possibly

```
 Expression<Func<ApplicationUser, bool>> IsActiveInChat = r => 
      (r.ConnectedToChat &&
        DbFunctions.DiffSeconds(DateTime.Now, r.LastChatActivity) < 10)
```

Then you can use this function as

```
public List<ApplicationUser> GetUsersConnectedToChat()
{
    List<ApplicationUser> users = Users
        .Where(IsActiveInChat)
        .ToList();

    return users;
}
```

The problem with this method is that you are limited to functions that SQL can handle. For example, you will get a NotSupportedException if you try

```
Expression<Func<ApplicationUser, bool>> isJan = r => 
     (r.LastChatActivity.ToSting("MMM")  == "JAN";
```

Comment: Thank you! A complete and helpful answer.