# Convert a Comma separated list into a list of INT using Automapper

Tags: c#, linq, automapper

I would like to know how to convert a string property which contains a comma delimited list of strings into a list of INT using Automapper. I found a similar question here in stack overflow but it throws an error on my end when I execute my LINQ. I am currently using C# 7 with Entity Framework 6 and Automapper v 5.1.1 (with Automapper.EF6 v0.5.0).

Data Source Example: [image: Here is my dataSource for that property]

```
ERROR: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32] GetCommaDelimitedStringAsAListOfInt(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

Here are my classes, my automapper configuration and method.

```
public class PracticeSource
{
  public string PracticeIds { get; set; } // will look something like "10, 589, 2587,"
}

public class PracticeDestination
{
  public List<int> PracticeIds { get; set; }
}

public static class AutoMapperConfiguration
{
  public static IMapper New Initialize()
  {
    var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    {
      cfg.CreateMap<PracticeContractOverview, PracticeContractOverviewReadModel>().ForMember(dest => dest.PracticeIds, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => GetCommaDelimitedStringAsAListOfInt(src.PracticeIds)));              
    })
    return configuration.CreateMapper();
  }

  private static List<int> GetCommaDelimitedStringAsAListOfInt(string model)
  {
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model))
    {
      return null;
    }
    return model.Split(',').Select(int.Parse).ToList();
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the exception that is being thrown?

Comment: Maybe you have a non `int` in the list. i.e. 1,4,5,,6,7,. Maybe you should exclude empty entries like so `.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)`.

Comment: @JonathonChase I just edited the post with the error that I am getting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Method cannot be translated into a store expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3846716/method-cannot-be-translated-into-a-store-expression)

Comment: Thank You @JonathonChase . I think that answers my question. Do you have any suggestions on possible solutions?

Comment: Changing `opt.MapFrom(src => GetCommaDelimitedStringAsAListOfInt(src.PracticeIds))` to `opt.MapFrom(src => src.PracticeIds?.Split(new[] { ','},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(int.Parse).ToList())` may do it.

Comment: @JonathonChase I updated my code to reflect your changes but I still get an error. ERROR: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String[] Split(Char[], System.StringSplitOptions)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.   I wonder if I can do this at the EF level, instead with AutoMapper. This way when I get the record from the DB I split it there and cast it.

Comment: @AdrianCruz Does it work with .Split(',')?

Comment: @JonathonChase no it doesn't work, it throws a similar Error but without the System.StringSplitOptions in the description.

Comment: @JonathonChase you can post "Possible duplicate of Method cannot be translated into a store expression" as an answer here, thank you.

Comment: @AdrianCruz I believe the question should be flagged and marked a duplicate rather than me answering it with a redirect.