# Custom LINQ Method into a store expression for re-usability and scaling later

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, expression

I'm trying to create a reusable function that can be used inside a LINQ Where clause, envisioning it would look like this:

```
using (var context = new AppDbContext())
{
    _MyObject = context.MyObject.AsNoTracking()

        //This works on MyObject (just FYI)
        .WhereActive() 

        //Hoping for something like this (on a Child object)
        .Where(o = IsActive(o.ChildObject)) 
        //Or
        .Where(o => o.MyChildObject.WhereActive())

    ;
}

return _MyObject;
```

This is my `BaseObject`, all objects will have `IsActive`:

```
public class BaseObject
{
    public BaseObject()
    {
        Oid = Guid.NewGuid();
        IsActive = true;
    }

    [Key]
    public Guid Oid { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

In the first example, I am using a `.WhereActive()`, this works fine:

```
public static class BaseObjectHelper
{
    public static IQueryable<T> WhereActive<T>(this IQueryable<T> query)
        where T : Entities.Base.BaseObject
    {
        return query.Where(b => b.IsActive);
    }
}
```

The issue I have is that I don't know how to create a method or function that can go into a `Where` clause like so:

> .Where(o = IsActive(o.MyChildObject))

Alternatively:

> .Where(o => o.MyChildObject.WhereActive())

Class examples:

```
public class MyObject : BaseObject
{
    [Display(Name = "My Child Object")]
    [Required]
    public Guid? MyChildObjectID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("MyChildObjectID")]
    public virtual MyChildObject MyChildObject{ get; set; }
}

public class MyChildObject : BaseObject
{
}
```

Please let me know where I can gather information to solve my issue, not sure where to start as I have tried a few ways but not working within LINQ.

Tried and did not work:

```
private bool IsActive(Menu menu)
{
    if (menu.IsActive)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Error reported:

> System.NotSupportedException: 'LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean IsActive(x.x.x.MyChildObject)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.'

I'm also would like to avoid slowing down the queries, I believe some of the example I reviewed required looping through the list to filter out the initial list.

I can accept using something like the below, but would like to add conditions to the expression later if needed:

```
.Where(o => o.MyChildObject.IsActive)
```

**Update with AsExandable()**

```
_MenuItems = context.MyObject.AsNoTracking()

    .Include(m => m.MyChildObject)

    .WhereActive()
    .AsExpandable().Where(a => IsActive.Invoke(a.MyChildObject))

    .ToList();


Func<Menu, bool> IsActive { get; } = bo => bo.IsActive;
```

> System.NotSupportedException: 'LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean IsActive(x.x.x.MyChildObject)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.'

Comment: `IQueryable` processors don't like (can't translate) custom methods.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Method cannot be translated into a store expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3846716/method-cannot-be-translated-into-a-store-expression)

Comment: is this just because you made the function private?

Comment: Instead of `Func<Menu, bool> IsActive { get; } = bo => bo.IsActive;` use `Expression<Func<Menu, bool>> IsActive { get; } = bo => bo.IsActive;` I have included it below in my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of defining methods like:

```
private bool IsActive(MyChildObject obj)
{
    return obj.IsActive;
}
```

Try to define it as a property returning an expression:

```
Expression<Func<ParentObject, bool>> IsActive { get; } = p => p.MyChildObject.IsActive;
```

Then you can do something like this in Linq:

```
return query.Where(IsActive);
```

Alternativly you can use LinqKit (https://www.nuget.org/packages/LinqKit/). Then you can define expression like a class field:

```
readonly Expression<Func<MyChildObject, bool>> IsActive = ch => ch.IsActive;
```

And write LINQ query like:

```
return query.AsExpandable().Where(a => IsActive.Invoke(a.MyChildObject));
```

Comment: Your second/last example gives and error: `'LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean Invoke(x.MyChildObject)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.` I am using `.AsExpandable()` as well.  The first example does work, but isn't generic enough, I would like to use the Expression on a `BaseObject` where I pass MyChildObject to the Expression, but not sure how to do that if it is even possible.

Comment: @Derek Can you show me your query with AsExpandable()?

Comment: I added an update `Update with AsExandable()`, I'm sure it's how I tried to use it.

Comment: @Derek have you had any other issues with this? Does it work as expected?

Comment: Unfortunately it isn't working.  using `.AsExpandable().Where(a => IsActive.Invoke(a.MyChildObject))` with `Expression<Func<MyChildObject, bool>> IsActive { get; } = bo => bo.IsActive;` is giving me this error: `'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.PropertyExpression' to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression'.'`

Comment: @derek OK I know what the problem is. Finally you need to use class fields instead of properties or assign property to variable and use this variable. I checked it and it works. Look at the updated answer

Comment: Your updated LinqKit is working, I will mark it as the answer.  I have a bit of thinking to do as my initial `BaseObjectHelper` idea is a bit more complicated than when I first started the project, that is out of scope for this question. Thank you for your help!