# How to assign stored procedure result to a entity inside select statement in entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I want to assign GetMajorMileStone(projecttask.ProjectTaskId) result to MajorMilestone.
I tried but getting following error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method
>   'System.Data.Objects.ObjectResult`1[.Poco.GetMajorMileStone_Result]
>   GetMajorMileStone(System.Nullable`1[System.Guid])' method, and this
>   method cannot be translated into a store expression.'

Here is my code:

```
    public ProjectsPayload GetProjectSchedule(int projectid, bool includeArchived, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, int userId)
    {
        using (var db = new Entities())
        {
            try
            {
                db.CommandTimeout = 1200;

                var query = from project in db.Project.Where(t => (t.Active || t.TempActive) && t.ProjectId == projectid)
                            join UP in db.User_X_Project on project.ProjectId equals UP.ProjectId
                            where (UP.UserId == userId && UP.Active)
                            orderby (project.Priority ?? int.MaxValue)
                            orderby (project.ProjectTitle)
                            select new
                            {
                                Project = project,

                                ProjectTask = from projecttask in project.ProjectTask.Where(t => t.Active && (
                                                                                                                (includeArchived == true && t.TaskStatusId == (int?)TaskStatus.Archived) ||
                                                                                                                (includeArchived == false && t.TaskStatusId != (int?)TaskStatus.Archived))
                                              || t.TaskStatusId != (int?)TaskStatus.Planned)
                                              join schedule in project.ProjectTask.SelectMany(p => p.ProjectTaskSchedule) on projecttask.ProjectTaskId equals schedule.ProjectTaskId
                                              join daily in db.ProjectTaskSchedule.SelectMany(p => p.DailyStatus) on schedule.ProjectTaskScheduleId equals daily.ProjectTaskScheduleId
                                              where schedule.Active && daily.Active && projecttask.Active && schedule.ResourceId == userId && (
                                                            (EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(daily.Date) >= EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(startDate.Date) &&
                                                            EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(daily.Date) <= EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(endDate.Date))
                                                            )
                                              orderby schedule.StartDate
                                              select new
                                              {

                                                  ProjectTask = projecttask,                                                    
                                                  ProjectTaskSchedule = from projecttaskschedule in projecttask.ProjectTaskSchedule.Where(t => t.Active && t.ResourceId == userId)
                                                                        select new
                                                                        {
                                                                            ProjectTaskSchedule = projecttaskschedule,
                                                                            DailyStatus = projecttaskschedule.DailyStatus.Where(t => t.Active),

                                                                        },
                                                  CritiCality = from cr in db.CritiCality.Where(ts => ts.ProjectTaskId == projecttask.ProjectTaskId) select cr,
                                                  MMDetails = from mm in db.MMDetails.Where(ts => ts.ProjectTaskId == projecttask.ProjectTaskId) select mm,
                     MajorMilestone = db.GetMajorMileStone(projecttask.ProjectTaskId).FirstOrDefault(),
            }


                            };

                var materialized = query.AsEnumerable();
                var result = materialized.Select(t => new ProjectsPayload
                {
                    ProjectId = t.Project.ProjectId,
                    ProjectTitle = t.Project.ProjectTitle,
                    Priority = t.Project.Priority,
                    ProjectDescription = t.Project.ProjectDescription,
                    ProjectTask = t.Project.ProjectTask.Select(x => new ProjectTaskPayload
                    {
                        Duration = x.Duration,
                        Hours = x.Hours,
                        IsOngoing = x.IsOngoing,
                        IsSummaryTask = x.IsSummaryTask,
                        Priority = x.Priority,
                        ParentTaskId = x.ParentTaskId,
                        ProjectId = x.ProjectId,
                        ProjectTaskId = x.ProjectTaskId,
                        TaskAcceptanceId = x.TaskAcceptanceId,
                        TaskStatusId = x.TaskStatusId,
                        TaskTitle = x.TaskTitle,
                        TaskTypeId = x.TaskTypeId,
                        IsMileStone = x.IsMileStone,
                        IsTimeAwayTask = x.IsTimeAwayTask,
                        AutoSize = x.AutoSize,
                        IsArchivedTasksInSummary = x.IsArchivedTasksInSummary,
                        IsASAP = x.IsASAP,
                        IsAutoCompleteEnable = x.IsAutoCompleteEnable,
                        IsSharedDiffSchedules = x.IsSharedDiffSchedules,
                        LongDescription = x.LongDescription,
                        OwnerId = x.OwnerId,
                        ShowInSummaryTask = x.ShowInSummaryTask,
                        SubTypeID = x.SubTypeID,
                        MMDetails1 = x.MMDetails1.Select(MD => new MMDetailsPayload { MajorMilestoneId = MD.MajorMilestoneId, ProjectTaskId = MD.ProjectTaskId, MMDetailsId = MD.MMDetailsId, Slack = MD.Slack }),
                        ProjectTaskSchedule = x.ProjectTaskSchedule.Select(a => new ProjectsTaskSchedulePayload
                        {
                            ProjectTaskScheduleId = a.ProjectTaskScheduleId,
                            StartDate = a.StartDate,
                            EndDate = a.EndDate,
                            ProjectTaskId = a.ProjectTaskId,
                            ResourceId = a.ResourceId,
                            ArchiveEndDate = a.ArchiveEndDate,
                            ArchiveStartDate = a.ArchiveStartDate,
                            IsSharedTask = a.IsSharedTask,
                            TimeUnitId = a.TimeUnitId,
                            DailyStatus = a.DailyStatus.Select(Ds => new DailyStatusPayload
                            {
                                Active = Ds.Active,
                                ActualHours = Ds.ActualHours,
                                DailyStatusId = Ds.DailyStatusId,
                                Date = Ds.Date,
                                ProjectTaskScheduleId = Ds.ProjectTaskScheduleId,
                                IsCloseOutDay = Ds.IsCloseOutDay,
                                Priority = Ds.Priority
                            })
                        }).ToList(),
                        CritiCality = x.CritiCality.Select(c => new CriticalityPayload { CriticalityId = c.CriticalityId, CriticalityTypeId = c.CriticalityTypeId, ProjectTaskId = c.ProjectTaskId }).ToList(),

                    }).ToList()
                }).FirstOrDefault();
                return result;
            }
            catch (EntityException ex)
            {
                if (ex.Message == connectionException)
                    throw new FaultException(dbException);
                else
                    throw new FaultException(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }

My result is like this, I want all entities(Criticality,MMDetails and MajorMileStone), Not only MajorMileStone
```

[MajorMileStone Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/on5NU.jpg)

Comment: do you able to solve it?

Comment: No.............

Comment: I have edited my post FYR... please open link 'MajorMileStoneResult'

Comment: I can't separate my query, if I do I can't get 'project' in query2

Answer (score 0):

I separate multiple simple query for testing. Please try to execute below two query and check whether successful or not.

```
// First query to get project
var query1 =  from project in db.Project.Where(t => (t.Active || t.TempActive) && t.ProjectId == projectid)
                            join UP in db.User_X_Project on project.ProjectId equals UP.ProjectId
                            where (UP.UserId == userId && UP.Active)
                            orderby (project.Priority ?? int.MaxValue)
                            orderby (project.ProjectTitle)
                            .Select new { project = project }.ToList();

// Second query to get projecttask from query1.project and execute store procedure
var query2 = from projecttask in query1.project.ProjectTask.Where(t => t.Active && (
                            (includeArchived == true && t.TaskStatusId == (int?)TaskStatus.Archived) ||
                            (includeArchived == false && t.TaskStatusId != (int?)TaskStatus.Archived)) ||
                             t.TaskStatusId != (int?)TaskStatus.Planned)
                             join schedule in query1.project.ProjectTask.SelectMany(p => p.ProjectTaskSchedule) on projecttask.ProjectTaskId equals schedule.ProjectTaskId
                             join daily in db.ProjectTaskSchedule.SelectMany(p => p.DailyStatus) on schedule.ProjectTaskScheduleId equals daily.ProjectTaskScheduleId
                             where schedule.Active && daily.Active && projecttask.Active && schedule.ResourceId == userId && (
                             (EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(daily.Date) >= EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(startDate.Date) &&
                             EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(daily.Date) <= EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(endDate.Date))
                             )
                             orderby schedule.StartDate
                             .Select new 
                            {                                 
                                MajorMilestone = db.GetMajorMileStone(projecttask.ProjectTaskId).FirstOrDefault(),
                            }.ToList();
```

Let me know it has result or not. In the meantime you can check this "[Method cannot be translated into a store expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3846716/method-cannot-be-translated-into-a-store-expression)" 
It has link to article about what not to do with linq. Nested Linq like this is best to avoid and better to split up the query. If it affects the execution time, it better to execute raw sql.

Comment: Yes. GetMajorMileStone is actual stored procedure

Comment: Tried with your code but not working getting build errors:  ProjectTask>>' does not contain a definition for 'AsEnumerble' and no accessible extension method 'AsEnumerble' accepting a first argument of type 'IQueryable<<anonymous type

Comment: What is your dotnet version?  I think missing packages.try add Using system.data

Comment: I have edited my post with actual method. please look into that

Comment: .Net version is 4.6

Comment: The problem is this line db.GetMajorMileStone(projecttask.ProjectTaskId).FirstOrDefault(). Look like cannot translate sql from linq

Comment: Can you try? db.GetMajorMileStone(projecttask.ProjectTaskId).AsEnumerable(). FirstOrDefault()

Comment: I tried with this instead of stored procedure but getting count=0,

Comment: MajorMilestone = from pt in db.ProjectTask.Where(ts => ts.ProjectTaskId == projecttask.ProjectTaskId)  join mm in db.MMDetails on pt.ProjectTaskId equals mm.ProjectTaskId  join mmd in db.MajorMilestone on mm.MajorMilestoneId equals mmd.ProjectTaskId select mmd,

Comment: I tried like this working fine but outside that query. var v= from pt in db.ProjectTask.Where(ts => ts.ProjectTaskId == projecttask.ProjectTaskId) join mm in db.MMDetails on pt.ProjectTaskId equals mm.ProjectTaskId join mmd in db.MajorMilestone on mm.MajorMilestoneId equals mmd.ProjectTaskId select mmd

Comment: So now there is no error but the result is zero?? The query looks correct to me.

Comment: Tried this- db.GetMajorMileStone(projecttask.ProjectTaskId).AsEnumerable(). FirstOrDefault()----getting same exception

Comment: if we writeLINQ query inside select statement  there is no exception but result is 0. if we assign to separate variable  out side---getting the result

Comment: Can try my edited code? If really still can't work, must break down LINQ to analyze the issue.