# LINQ query expression versus fluent (dot) notation

Tags: .net, linq, syntax

```
Dim namePriceQuery = From prod In products
                     Select prod.Name, prod.Price
```

OR

```
Dim namePriceQuery = products.select(function(x) New With{ Key .newName =x.name _ 
, Key .newPrice= x.price})
```

To my knowledge the only difference is with with the second expression has the benefits of the [Key](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531349.aspx) keyword. What exactly is the difference between the two?? And what scenarios would I choose to use one or the other in? What are the pros and cons of one vs the other?

I am assuming the C# syntax equivalent will work the same and should be used in similar before mention scenarios. Thank you very much!

Comment: which itself links to yet another dupe. [Which LINQ syntax do you prefer? Fluent or Query Expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/214500/which-linq-syntax-do-you-prefer-fluent-or-query-expression) both have good answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either one works the same but I would choose the one that is most readable.

Comment: which would you consider most readable. i prefer the linq way myself

Comment: The Fluent API is harder to grasp at first, but all the senior DEVs I know are fluent all the way.

Answer (score 0):

Both statements are equal. Linq queries formulated with linq syntax are translated into the appropriate method calls.

Select what fits you best in terms of readability and/or makes your code more understandable. If you get really complex queries, using select many and grouping the linq syntax is much better to read.

I switch between both forms of linq queries depending on the situation.