# How to convert comma delimited string to a List<T> where T is unknown until runtime

Tags: c#, list, generics, reflection

Given a function

```
T Func<T>(string val) {}
```

where the goal is to convert val to T, where T could be int, or could also be List (in which case val is a comma delimited list of things that hopefully can be converted to Ts

ignoring the int version, because it is easy, how do you convert the string to a List

Comment: This seems a bit obvious to me. A comma separated string would contain strings. Do you mean you want to convert them after the fact?

Comment: The code above converts "1,2,3" to new List<int> {1, 2, 3} where T might be List<int> but also might just be int or DateTime, or any other type. It will also haand lists of any arbirtrary type where the comma delimited string can contain elements of any type.

Comment: How would you ensure that a string represents any arbitrary type, other than the mentioned value types? For complex types what would `val` represent: the type name, a field value? Without getting into actual applications and usage, what you are trying to do does not seem feasible.

Comment: The conversion from string to complex type is handled by the ConvertType method, anything that it would handle deserialization of the complex types. That is not the point of the question though. The question was really about how to instantiate a T where T could be int, or say List<TT>, then how to determine what TT was. syntax for casting to TT, then syntax for adding an object to List<TT> instead of the strongly typed Add.Its feasible, because it works.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert string array to int array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9624355/convert-string-array-to-int-array)

Comment: not quite a duplicate,because it is not known what the type of array/list is ahead of time. It could be a list of ints, or a list of double, or a list of Datetime, or a list of enum, and the code in my answer will handle them all

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**As I was entering this question, the answers came to me, so I leave this question answered as a guide to others.**

I have a function such as

```
T Func<T>(string val) {}
```

Inside this function I do various processing, one item of which is to convert the val to a T.

I have another function which I use for this purpose

```
T ChangeType<T>(this object value)
```

This function is mainly a wrapper around Convert.ChangeType with some additional processing,  to handle things that Convert.ChangeType can't do out of the box (stolen from stackoverflow elsewhere)

Everything works great for most types, but is some cases T is a List and val is then a comma separated list of values.

I can correctly determine if T is a List via

```
if (returnType.IsGenericType && returnType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>))
```

and then I can instantiate the appropriate list return type as follows

```
T list = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(returnType);
```

Now, I need to call my ChangeType on each split value from the string, and add them to the list.

```
var method = typeof (XmlUtil).GetMethod("ChangeType", new [] {typeof(object)});
var genericMethod = method.MakeGenericMethod(subType);
var convertedItem = genericMethod.Invoke(null, new [] {item});
var subType = returnType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
```

All good so far. Now I have a

```
dynamic list; //instantiated with a List<TT>
var convertedItem; // which is typed as an object, instantiated with a type TT.
```

How do I call

```
list.Add(convertedItem);
```

the dynamic will handle the fact that I don't have a known interface for the list, but at runtime I get an error because I am trying to add an object to a list, even though the object is actually of type T as instantiated.

The ultimate answer, is to cast the List as a non-generic IList, where you can then add object.

```
System.Collections.IList list2;
list2 = (System.Collections.IList) list;
list2.Add(convertedItem);
```

Comment: Please, separate answer and question

Comment: I have split them as requested