# asp.net array / arraylist error

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, arrays, loops, arraylist

I'm working on something relatively simple (or so I thought) and need a bit of help.

I am trying to create a dynamic amount of comma separated strings.

I have a variable (numberOfStrings) which is the number of different strings I need.
I just want to loop thru the aryDrivers and assign then to the different strings.

```
Dim aryHeats(numberOfStrings - 1) As ArrayList

Dim aryDrivers() As String
aryDrivers = txtBatch.Text.Split(",")

For i As Integer = 0 To aryDrivers.Length - 1
    For j As Integer = 0 To aryHeats.Length - 1
        aryHeats(j).Add(aryDrivers(i) & ",")
    Next
Next
```

For some reason I'm getting an error in the loop when I try to "ADD" the string.

Thoughts?

Thanks!

**** Update **

Maybe this will help explain more what I'm trying to do.
I have a string:

s = A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z

i'm passing a variable (numberOfHeats) lets use 4.

i would like to then have 4 strings (so I am wanted to use array)

```
ary(0) = A,E,I,M,Q,U,Y
ary(1) = B,F,J,N,R,V,Z
ary(2) = C,G,K,O,S,W
ary(3) = D,H,L,P,T,X
```

hopefully that clears this up.

Comment: Do you want to add anyDrivers string array items to anyHeats array list?

Comment: yes. i'm getting an error. Object is nothing.

Comment: i was able to figure this out, but it won't let me post and answer until tomorrow. the key was I just needed to not declare it as array or arraylist but as a string.  Dim aryHeats(numberOfHeats - 1) As String

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397910.aspx), although [i hate VB.NET method syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9039282/284240):

```
Dim text = "A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z"
Dim numberOfHeats = 4
Dim aryHeats As String()() = s.Split(","c).
        Select(Function(w, index) New With {.Word = w, .Index = index}).
        GroupBy(Function(x) x.Index Mod numberOfHeats).
        Select(Function(grp) grp.Select(Function(x) x.Word).ToArray()).
        ToArray()
```

**Explanation**: it takes the initial string and split it in words (comma as separator). Then it transforms the word and the according index in the String-Array to an anonymous type with `Word` and `Index` as properties. This list will be grouped by `Index Mod numberOfHeats`(the number of arrays you want). This implicitely orders by your desired result. The last step is to transform the groups to a jagged array.

Result:

```
(0) 
    (0) "A" 
    (1) "E" 
    (2) "I" 
    (3) "M" 
    (4) "Q" 
    (5) "U" 
    (6) "Y" 
(1) 
    (0) "B" 
    (1) "F" 
    (2) "J" 
    (3) "N" 
    (4) "R" 
    (5) "V" 
    (6) "Z" 
(2)     
    (0) "C" 
    (1) "G" 
    (2) "K" 
    (3) "O" 
    (4) "S" 
    (5) "W" 
(3) 
    (0) "D" 
    (1) "H" 
    (2) "L" 
    (3) "P" 
    (4) "T" 
    (5) "X"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Dim aryHeats(numberOfStrings - 1) As ArrayList

Dim aryDrivers() As String
aryDrivers = txtBatch.Text.Split(",")

For i As Integer = 0 To aryDrivers.Length - 1
    aryHeats(  i Mod aryHeats.Length  ).Add(aryDrivers(i) & ",")

Next
```

Comment: okay, i see what you're trying, but that doesn't use my numberOfHeats variable. I updated my post to give a better example of what i'm trying to do. thanks.