# Confused by Linq query on DataTable implementing 'Distinct'

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

I'm trying to return a set of distinct values from a DataTable using LINQ.

This is my code without the 'Distinct' part as I'm struggling to formulate the proper linq statement:

```
 DataTable gridData = RgClientData.DataSource as DataTable;
   var results = from myRow in gridData .AsEnumerable()
             select (myRow.Field<string>("AssignedUser"));
```

Just adding "Distinct()" to the end of the select does not work. I'm wrestling with the syntax because I don't fully understand how the 'Distinct' part relates to the Linq query.

Could someone point me in the right direction...thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your query needs to be enclosed within parentheses in order to add `Distinct` to the end of it:

```
var results = (from myRow in gridData .AsEnumerable()
              select myRow.Field<string>("AssignedUser")).Distinct();
```

Or you could switch to the fluent syntax:

```
var results = gridData.AsEnumerable()
                      .Select(myRow => myRow.Field<string>("AssignedUser"))
                      .Distinct();
```

Comment: Thank you, this works great and has also made me realise why I was getting so confused - I didn't appreciate there are two ways of writing LINQ expressions. This has lead me to [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/214500/which-linq-syntax-do-you-prefer-fluent-or-query-expression) for further reading...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 var results = (from myRow in gridData .AsEnumerable()
             select (myRow.Field<string>("AssignedUser")).Distinct();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] distinctcolumn = (from b in datatable1.AsEnumerable()
                           select b.Field<string>"colimnname")).Distinct().ToArray();
```

columnname is the name of column whose distinct values you want

you get string array distinctcolumn you can use it as you need to.

Comment: This is exactly the same as the accepted answer from 4 months ago. At the risk of stating the obvious, you should check that no-one has already posted your answer before writing a post - at least check the accepted answer...