# The type of the expression in the select clause is incorrect. Type inference failed in the call to 'Select'

Tags: c#, linq

I am learning LINQ and was trying out this example related to `select` clause.

```
var q = from c in xmlDoc.Descendants("site").Where(tech => tech.Attribute("technical").Value == "true")
                   .Select(n => new { SiteName = n.Element("name").Value});
```

The above query is giving me an error:
`The type of the expression in the select clause is incorrect. Type inference failed in the call to 'Select'.`

What is wrong int the above syntax?

Apart from the above, I have to convert the `selected` options `ToDictionary`. How can be done in the same query via LINQ?

The third question that I had in my mind was about different syntax for writing the same query (e: the second method writing example below). What syntax is preferred and why?

```
from c in xmlDoc.Descendants
where c.Attriubute("technical").Value == "true"
select c.Element("site").Value;
```

Comment: does the second query work or it is also giving you error?

Comment: Not, too sure about the error, could you post your sample XML ?

Comment: @Habib.OSU: Here's the xml. http://pastebin.com/SCSvPrg8

Comment: @user1372448, link seems to be broken

Comment: One question per post, please. Your third question is [covered in depth here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/214500/which-linq-syntax-do-you-prefer-fluent-or-query-expression)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.
you have mixed lambda expression with linq syntax. started with linq and end with lambda expression. try this

```
 var q = xmlDoc.Descendants("site").Where(tech => tech.Attribute("technical").Value == "true")
                   .Select(n => new { SiteName = n.Element("name").Value});
```

or you should be using the whole query in linq

```
var q = from c in xmlDoc.Descendants("site") where c.Attribute("technical").Value == "true"
                   select new { SiteName = c.Element("name").Value};
```

2.
just use ToDictionary in the end of query

```
var q = xmlDoc.Descendants("site").Where(tech => tech.Attribute("technical").Value == "true")
                   .Select(n => new { SiteName = n.Element("name").Value,Key= n.Element("id").Value }).ToDictionary(n=>n.Key,l=>l.SiteName);
```

n=>n.Key will the key for dictionary and l=>l.siteName will be value.

3.
There are two ways of create such queries one is using linq other is using methods that uses lambda expressions as parameter. both are easy, linq is somehow like SQL query while Methods use lambda are more like a short hand for manipulating data by description methods. i personally like method oriented way with lambda as its more sequentially readable.

Comment: Your terminology is incorrect, potentially confusingly so. [**Both** syntaxes are **Linq**: one is "Query Syntax", the other is "Method Syntax"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397947.aspx). Lambda expressions are something different entirely.

Comment: Thanks @AakashM i forgot to mention all Linq Methods are using lambda expression. you are right Query/Method Syntax are the correct terms.