# Need to convert this code to VB

Tags: c#, vb.net, ienumerable, c#-to-vb.net

I 'm not familiar with C#.NET at all. I need to convert this to VB. Can anyone please give me a hand?

```
public IEnumerable<CodecInfo> AudioCodecs
        {
            get { return softPhone.Codecs.Where(c => c.CodecType == CodecMediaType.Audio); }
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: this is just returning the Codecs collection filtered for CodecMediaType.Audio...

Comment: Translating code between languages is not really an appropriate question for SO...

Comment: There are online translators you can use [here](http://www.carlosag.net/tools/codetranslator/) is one oh them.

Comment: There are numerous online tools that for simple situations like this are very good. For example http://converter.telerik.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Public ReadOnly Property AudioCodecs As IEnumerable(Of CodecInfo)
    Get
        Return From c In softPhone.Codecs
               Where c.CodecType = CodecMediaType.Audio
    End Get
End Property
```

<sub>Query syntax is much more readable than method syntax in VB.NET</sub>

Comment: *Query syntax is much more readable in VB.NET* - That's true, it's even more powerfull than in C#

Comment: How is that more readable than the same query in C#?  `from c in softPhone.Codecs where c.CodecType == CodecMediaType.Audio`, right?  Looks pretty easy to read to me (except for being in a comment).

Comment: I don't see how it's more readable than the C# version.  LINQ syntax is fairly consistent across both languages.  The only key difference here is the C# version is compressed for space to put the property accessor and code on a single line, where the VB.Net forces you to be multiline, but that's not the query syntax itself.

Comment: Maybe it's not the best example, so have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9039282/284240

Comment: You have both misunderstood my note so i've edited my answer to clarify it (hopefully).

Answer (score 3):

```
Public ReadOnly Property AudioCodecs() As IEnumerable(Of CodecInfo)
    Get
        Return softPhone.Codecs.Where(Function(c) c.CodecType = CodecMediaType.Audio)
    End Get
End Property
```

In future you can use a C#-VB.NET converter:

http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/

Answer (score 0):

```
Public ReadOnly Property AudioCodecs() As IEnumerable(Of CodecInfo)
    Get
        Return softPhone.Codecs.Where(Function(c) c.CodecType = CodecMediaType.Audio)
    End Get
End Property
```