# How can I reformat this to use the other kind of LINQ Query format?

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following code:

```
public IList<Reference.Grid> GetGrid(string pk)
{
    return (
        from d in _referenceRepository.GetPk(pk)
        select new Reference.Grid
        {
            PartitionKey = d.PartitionKey,
            RowKey = d.RowKey,
            Value = d.Value,
            Order = d.Order
        })
}
```

I am new to LINQ but I understand there are two ways I can write a select. Can someone help by telling me how I can rewrite this the other way. Also are there any differences and which way do people most often use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two ways you have mentioned are method- and query-syntax. You have used query-syntax.

This is the same in method syntax:

```
public IList<Reference.Grid> GetGrid(string pk)
{
    return (
    _referenceRepository.GetPk(pk)
    .Select(d => new Reference.Grid
    {
        PartitionKey = d.PartitionKey,
        RowKey = d.RowKey,
        Value = d.Value,
        Order = d.Order
    })).ToList();
}
```

Note that i've changed it to use `ToList` to create a `List<Reference.Grid>`. otherwise it would be an `IEnumerable<Reference.Grid>`.

> Also are there any differences and which way do people most often use?

Use what is most readable and works. There are some methods not supported in query-syntax.

[MSDN: LINQ Query Syntax versus Method Syntax (C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397947.aspx)

[Which LINQ syntax do you prefer? Fluent or Query Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214500/which-linq-syntax-do-you-prefer-fluent-or-query-expression)

Comment: Thanks. Do people most often use this way?

Answer (score 2):

The other way would look like this:

```
_referenceRepository.GetPk(pk)
                    .Select(d => new Reference.Grid 
                                 { 
                                     PartitionKey = d.PartitionKey, 
                                     RowKey = d.RowKey, 
                                     Value = d.Value, 
                                     Order = d.Order 
                                 });
```

The *query syntax* you used is translated by the compiler into the *method syntax* I used, so they are both compiled to the same IL.
You should choose the one you are more comfortable with. I like the method syntax better as I find it more readable, but YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

To make it more general:

```
from item in someSource select new{item.Something}
someSource.Select(item => new{item.Something}

from item in someSource where item.SomeProperty == someValue
someSource.Where(item => new{item.Something}

from item in someSource group item.Property1 by item.Property2
someSource.GroupBy(item => item.Property2, item => item.Property1)

from item in someSource orderby item.Property1
someSource.OrderBy(item => item.Property1)

from item in someSource orderby item.Property1 descending
someSource.OrderByDescending(item => item.Property1)
```

Some of the first form of each are not complete as they need to end with a `select` or a `group by`. This doesn't apply to the second form, so you have a complete query in the `.OrderBy` even though you don't after `orderby`. When converting, remember that `.Select(x => x)` can be added to every query and make no logical difference, by equivalence, with the last example of `orderby descending` adding `select item` to the end makes it a complete query that is equivalent to the `OrderByDescending` given below.

Adding several together:

```
from item in someSource
  where item.Property1 == 43
  orderby item.Property2
  select new {item.Property3, item.Property4}

someSource
  .Where(item => item.Propert1 == 43)
  .OrderBy(item => item.Propert2)
  .Select(item => new{item.Propert3, item.Property4});
```

Because each method call is separate, we don't need to use the same terms in the lambda with the second type, so this is equivalent to:

```
someSource
  .Where(x=> x.Propert1 == 43)
  .OrderBy(y=> y.Propert2)
  .Select(z=> new{z.Propert3, z.Property4});
```

But we can't do that with the first form, because it's a single clause with each term defined only once. Because the methods are all extensions, it is also equivalent to:

```
  Queryable.Select(
    Queryable.OrderBy(
      Queryable.Where(someSource, x => x.Propert1 == 43),
      y=> y.Propert2),
    z=> new{z.Propert3, z.Property4});
```

OR

```
  Enumerable.Select(
    Enumerable.OrderBy(
      Enumerable.Where(someSource, x => x.Propert1 == 43),
      y=> y.Propert2),
    z=> new{z.Propert3, z.Property4});
```

Which will work with any .NET language, even without support for Linq or extension methods in that language.

LinqPad is great for examining queries (or any C# code) in a variety of ways, and one of them is turning the query syntax into the equivalent method syntax (the former is compiled to the latter, anyway).

Personally, I find I switch between the two a lot. I'll favour query syntax for larger queries, and I'll favour method syntax if the overall expression contains a high ratio of calls that don't have a query syntax equivalent to those that do, but there are plenty where it's just a matter of whatever I typed at the time.