# Any difference between QueryAsyc and querying the table using lambda?

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-8, lambda

I'm using SQLite in a Windows 8 application I'm running and was wondering if there was any sort of performance issue between using the following two lines of code:

```
conn.Table<Chemistry>().Where(ch => ch.case_id == CaseId).ToListAsync();
```

vs

```
conn.QueryAsync<Chemistry>("SELECT * FROM Chemistry WHERE Case_Id = ?", CaseId);
```

They both work and I prefer to use the lambda expression as opposed to the string query. Just wondering if there are any repercussions when doing this.

Answer (score 0):

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214500/which-linq-syntax-do-you-prefer-fluent-or-query-expression) and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/389136/Difference-between-LINQ-and-Lambda-Expression-inte).  The gist is, assuming equivalent statements, they produce the same IL so the performance is identical.  There are some things which are easier to express in the query form.