# lambda expression vb.net for max value in a datatable

Tags: vb.net, lambda

I have a datatable called table1 with a column called column1 that is an integer.

How can i get the max value of the column with a lambda expression in vb net?

thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Dim max As Int32 = table1.AsEnumerable().
    Max(Function(r) r.Field(Of Int32)("column1"))
```

or in query syntax, what is [often more readable in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9039282/284240):

```
Dim values =  From row In table1.AsEnumerable()
              Select row.Field(Of Int32)("column1")
Dim maxValue As Int32 = values.Max()
```