# C# Skipwhile to VB skipWhile

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have code in C#

```
string fileNameOnly = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(sKey);
string token = fileNameOnly.Remove(fileNameOnly.LastIndexOf('_'));
string number = new string(token.SkipWhile(Char.IsLetter).ToArray());
```

And i want it in VB

```
Dim fileNameOnly As String = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(sKey)
Dim token As String = fileNameOnly.Remove(fileNameOnly.LastIndexOf("_"c))
Dim number As New String(token.SkipWhile([Char].IsLetter).ToArray())
```

I have tried that but did not work! Is there something similar to use.
What it does is look at a file name and only use the number part of it and skip all letters and all after `_`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [`AddressOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y72ewk2b.aspx) in VB.NET:

```
Dim number As New String(token.SkipWhile(AddressOf Char.IsLetter).ToArray())
```

You could also use `Function`:

```
Dim number As New String(token.SkipWhile(Function(c)Char.IsLetter(c)).ToArray())
```

In VB.NET i often use multiple lines and combine query+method syntax to avoid the [ugly `Function`/`AddressOf`  keywords](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9039282/284240).

```
Dim numberChars = From c In token
                  Skip While Char.IsLetter(c)
Dim numbers = New String(numberChars.ToArray())
```