# Decipher LINQ to Objects query involving strings

Tags: c#, linq-to-objects

(Disclaimer: I am new to LINQ, and I did do my homework, but all my research came up with examples that deal with strings directly.  My code deals with an `ObservableCollection` of objects where each object contains a string.)

I have the following code:

```
public class Word
{
    public string _word { get; set; }
    // Other properties.
}

ObservableCollection<Word> items = new ObservableCollection<Word>();

items.Add(new Word() { _word = "Alfa" });
items.Add(new Word() { _word = "Bravo" });
items.Add(new Word() { _word = "Charlie" });
```

I am trying to find the words that have an "r" in them:

```
IEnumerable<Word> subset = from ii in items select ii;
subset = subset.Where(p => p._word.Contains("r"));
```

The above works (I get 'Bravo' and 'Charlie').

My question: I have devised the above LINQ query from bits and pieces of examples I found online/in books.

1. How does it do what it does?
2. Is there be a better/more straightforward way?

Thanks.

Comment: You're mixing query- and method syntax. Btw, why do you habe a class `Word` with a single property `-word` at all? Also, please follow [.NET Naming Conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229012(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @TimSchmelter The class contains other properties as I have shown with a comment - I did not detail them here.  Also, could you please expand on your comment re: query/method syntax? Which is which?

Comment: Query-syntax: `var query = from item in collection` method-syntax: `var query = collection.Select(item => item)`.  Here's a question about the pros and cons: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/214500/linq-fluent-and-query-expression-is-there-any-benefits-of-one-over-other

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve that you want more simple like below:

```
IEnumerable<Word> subset = items.Where(x => x._word.Contains("r"));
```

With the above linq query, you filter the collection called items using an extension method called `Where`. Each element in the collection of `items` that satisfies the filter in the `Where` method, it will be contained on the `subset`. Inside the `Where` you have defined your fitler, using a lambda expression. On the left side of `=>` you have your input -the random element of `items`, while on the right side of `=>` you have your output, which in your case will be either `true` or `false`. On the rigth side of `=>`, you usethe string's method called `Contains`, which in simple terms checks if the string you pass as a parameter to this method is contained in the property called `_word`, of the element `x`.

Comment: Yes, this works, thank you.  But is `Where` an extension method? I was under the impression that extension methods are those that you define yourself.  Sorry if this is a stupid question.

Comment: `Where` is an extension method defined in the `Enumerable`-class, but @Christos is wrong regarding the `Contains` method, it is a normal member method of the `String` class. You can read about extension methods here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx

Comment: @frankkoch oops you are correct. Thanks for pointing this out.