# Select multiple fields in lambda expression

Tags: vb.net, linq

I work through a linq book and just do not understand why

```
customers.where(function(x) x.city = "London").Select(function(y) new with{y.CompanyName, y.Country})
```

works (creating an anonyomous type, I got that) but

```
customers.where(function(x) x.city = "London").select(function(y) y.countryname, y.country)
```

doesnt work. Isnt it possible to select multiple fields in a select query?

Comment: Easy: because the second is not a valid syntax to create an anonymous type.

Comment: Is it possible to get a 'concrete' type out of it?

Comment: Yes, i've shown a way below in my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is:  the second is not a valid syntax to create an anonymous type.

So this:

```
new with{y.CompanyName, y.Country}
```

creates an anonymous type with two properties whereas this

```
y.countryname, y.countr
```

does create nothing but a compiler error.

It would make sense if you'd create a class `Company` and provide a constructor like:

```
Public Class Company
    Public Sub New(companyName As String, countryName As String)
        Me.Country = countryName
        Me.Name = companyName
    End Sub

    Public Country As String
    Public Name As String
End Class
```

Now you can use this syntax to create an `IEnumerable(Of Company)`:

```
Dim companies = customers.
    Where(Function(x) x.city = "London").
    Select(Function(x) New Company(x.CompanyName, x.Country))
```

or in query syntax ([which i like more in VB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9039282/284240)):

```
Dim companies = From c In customers
                Where c.City = "London"
                Select New Company(c.CompanyName, c.Country)
```

Comment: Hi Tim, this is very helpful for me and gives an hint to my all day long question how to handle anonymous types too. Thanks a lot!