# Enumerable order by rage in vb

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have the Vb code below i would like to know why it is failing at i.  I have done this is C# and it works fine.

```
Dim numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 4).OrderBy(i >= ran.Next()).ToList()
```

Comment: C# is a different language to VB.NET with a different syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because that is not valid syntax in VB.NET, you need [the ugly `Function` keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9039282/284240):

```
Dim numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 4).OrderBy(Function(i) i >= ran.Next()).ToList()
```

In VB.NET i almost always try to avoid that keyword, it hurts my eyes. So you can use this:

```
Dim numbers = From n In Enumerable.Range(1, 4)
              Order By n >= ran.Next()
Dim numList As List(Of Int32) = numbers.ToList()
```

But if you want to order randomly this should work:

```
Dim numbers = From n In Enumerable.Range(1, 4)
              Order By ran.Next()
Dim numList As List(Of Int32) = numbers.ToList()
```

Comment: I am using the random class to randomise the range any idea why this is not happening.