# sum of function in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, function, sum

I want to understand what means this code

```
Dim myValue As Double = range.Sum(Function(x) x.Positive)
```

range is a  List(Of Money).
I have to mention That I have this Private Class

```
Private Class Money
        Private m_Positive As Double
        Private m_Negative As Double
        Public Property Positive As Double
            Get
                Return m_Positive
            End Get
            Set(value As Double)
                m_Positive = value
            End Set
        End Property
        Public Property Negative As Double
            Get
                Return m_Negative
            End Get
            Set(value As Double)
                m_Negative= value
            End Set
        End Property
    End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a [Linq(to-Objects)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763068.aspx) query using [`Enumerable.Sum`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.sum(v=vs.95).aspx). It uses the property `Positive` of the class `Money` to sum all objects in the `List(Of Money)`. Therefore it uses a [Lambda Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531253.aspx) to project it.

It is similar to a loop:

```
Dim sum As Double = 0
For Each m As Money In range
    sum += m.Positive
Next
```

You could also use query syntax, which i often find more readable in VB.NET then using [the ugly `Function` keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9039282/284240):

```
Dim positives = From m As Money In range 
                Select m.Positive
Dim sum = positives.Sum()  ' this executes the query above '
```

Comment: I can not use query syntax because I am working with .NET 2.0 :(