# Cannot use Enumerable.Count with List, compiler assumes List.Count

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, linq

I haven't noticed this behaviour yet, maybe because i prefer query syntax in VB.NET and split the query and the execution-methods into different statements.

If i try to compile following simple query:

```
Dim wordList As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
Dim longWords As Int32 = wordList.Count(Function(word) word.Length > 100)
```

The compiler doesn't like this because he expects no arguments for `List.Count`:

> "Public Readonly Property Count As Integer" has no parameters and its return type cannot be indexed.

If i declare it as `IEnumerable(Of String)` it works as expected:

```
Dim wordSeq As IEnumerable(Of String) = New List(Of String)
Dim longWords As Int32 = wordSeq.Count(Function(word) word.Length > 100)
```

Why is that so? What prevents the compiler from using the `Enumerable` extension method [`Count`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb535181(v=vs.100).aspx) instead of the [`ICollection.Count`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27b47ht3(v=vs.110).aspx) property. Note that i've added `Imports System.Linq` and both `Option Strict` and `Option Infer` are `On`. I'm using.NET 4.0 (Visual Studio 2010).

I'm confused because in C# this works without a problem:

```
List<String> wordList  = new List<String>();
int longWordCount = wordList.Count(word => word.Length > 100);
```

Comment: Im not familiar with VB.NET but in C# a List has a Property `Count` which returns the length of the collection. You may be looking for the linq extention `Count` and getting the compiler "confused" ?

Comment: @AlexAnderson I suppose Tim's question comes down to: why is the compiler confused? The syntax makes it very clear you're looking for a method with one argument, not for a property - the VB.NET compiler should have no issue with his.

Comment: @AlexAnderson: The title suggests that Tim knows what is going on, just not why.

Comment: I'd just like to add that, if this is an one-off, an alternative to declaring the variable as `IEnumerable<T>` is using [`AsEnumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb335435(v=vs.100).aspx). E.g., `wordList.AsEnumerable().Count(...);`

Comment: *in C# this works without a problem*: So use C# :p. Just kidding :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's **by design**, quote from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384936.aspx):

> The situation is simpler with properties: if an extension method has the same name as a property of the class it extends, the extension method is not visible and cannot be accessed.

Comment: +1 So the VB.NET compiler is in this case(by design) not as smart as the C# compiler?

Comment: @TimSchmelter Not as smart, or it's by-design?

Comment: @TimSchmelter I'm trying to understand (from specs) where it comes from, I suppose it may be because of 11.8.1#6 but I'm not such sure...

Comment: It is visible and can be accessed - you just need to cast the object first, or use 'AsEnumerable'.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Keep in mind that it's a potentially ambigious situation, particularly so in VB.  What if the property in question is invocable, for example.  If `Count` returned a `Func<string, bool>` then what should the code do?

Comment: @DaveDoknjas yes, as Servy pointed out in his answer that's one of AsEnumerable() purposes. We were trying to point out the _reason_ for that behavior.

Comment: @Servy well it _may_ do what C# does (detect this issue and stop compilation). Well I guess there is a reason for that (in VB design) but I still can't figure out which one (but maybe what Tim said about their priorities).

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti You're forgetting the fundimental design goal of VB, to avoid failing at all costs and try to do *something* instead of failing, unlike C#'s design goal which is to inform the developer if there is an ambiguity so that they can clarify the intent.

Comment: @Servy :| yes, that's true. Automatic conversions between delegates should be a strong warning of that!

Answer (score 1):

In C#, only way to call a property is using property syntax (i.e) `instance.PropertyName` where as in Vb.Net there are two options.

```
Dim list As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)()
Dim count = list.Count() //Method 1
Dim count2 = list.Count  //Method 2
```

Assume you add a `Count` extension method with no parameters, what does `list.Count()` mean? It always gives priority to instance members so it points to Property.

Ok, What does `list.Count(Function(s) s.StartsWith("a"))` means? In this case it mean the extension method?

There is no consistency in the language then, I guess designers deliberately avoided this feature for consistency.

Comment: They could have designed it in this way: if there is a property **and** an extension method, use the property. In the other case use either the property or the method. (+1 however since it might be one of the  reasons)

Comment: But there is always that case (an extension method conflicts with an instance method) and it's addressed by specs (extension method is ignored) but it's not _this_ case.. In that case I'd agree it should fail but in this I'm sure there is a reason but I can't _see_ it.

Comment: Tim: yes, they could have done. But there is no consistency isn't it? I assume it is the matter of consistency in the language (Till someone comes with a fact we all can make only assumptions).

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: I guess Eric Lippert's answer to this  question would be "because it wasn't worth the cost of designing, implementing, testing and documenting it". I assume that the VB.NET compiler team also has to follow this rule. They gave a higher priority to the [power of LINQ's query syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9039282/284240).

Comment: Yeah, [Every feature is expensive](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/10/28/how-many-microsoft-employees-does-it-take-to-change-a-lightbulb.aspx). Even just 5 lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

If you cast to IEnumerable when you need the extension method, everything will be fine:

```
Dim longWords As Int32 = CType(wordList, IEnumerable(Of String)).Count(Function(word) word.Length > 100)
```

Or as dcastro mentioned in a comment:

```
Dim longWords As Int32 = wordList.AsEnumerable.Count(Function(word) word.Length > 100)
```

Comment: Then i would really, really prefer a two-liner ;)

Comment: Then I think the 'AsEnumerable' solution is better - it doesn't muddy up the statement too much.

Comment: Yes, but i would always wonder for what it's good since `List(Of T)` already implements `IEnumerable(Of T)`. In VB.NET i like this more: `Dim longWords = From word In wordList Where word.Length > 100  Dim count = longWords.Count()`. It's more readable, more maintainable, better to debug and you can reuse the `longWords` variable. It's also  as efficient. (+1 anyway)

Answer (score 1):

One of the primary purpose of the `AsEnumerable` method is specifically to be used when the type of an `IEnumerable` object has a member that takes precedence over one of the LINQ extension methods, so you should simply add in a call to `AsEnumerable` before calling `Count`, to remove the member conflict.