# IComparer for string that checks if x starts with y

Tags: c#, icomparer, startswith

I've got an array of strings and I need to get all strings, that start with some 'prefix'. I wanna use Array.BinarySearch(). Is it possible? And how should I write a comparer if so?

Comment: `BinarySearch` is for finding _one_ item in a _sorted_ array, which means you'll have to pre-sort the array based on that criteria.  If that's what you want then it's possible, but using a normal search routing would probably be more appropriate.  If you want to find _all_ items that start with a value then `BinarySearch` would not work at all.

Comment: Even if you could pull it off, it would not be more efficient than a linear search. The point of Binary searching is using it for multiple searches on the same set. If you are using it for just one search, just sorting the array would take longer than single linear search.

Comment: In a comment on an answer you mention that you have a sorted list of 100k strings, and another (also sorted?) list of 10k prefixes. What is your actual problem that you're trying to solve? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @SimonSvensson, I need to get 10 words from 100000 list of sorted words for each prefix from 10000 sorted list of prefixes

Comment: Do any of the prefixes overlap (e.g. does it contain `Foo` and `Foobar`?  Is the list of prefixes sorted?

Comment: @DStanley, prefixes are sorted. And they overlap (i.e. 'aaca', 'aaac')

Comment: The solution is to use trie

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot use `BinarySearch` in this case. You could use `Enumerable.Where` instead:

```
Dim query = From str In array Where str.StartsWith("prefix")
```

or with ([ugly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9039282/284240) in VB.NET) method synatx:

```
query = array.Where(Function(str) str.StartsWith("prefix"))
```

**Edit**: whoops, C#

```
var query = array.Where(s => s.StartsWith("prefix"));
```

Use `ToArray` if you want to create a new filtered array.

Comment: The thing is that I've got List<string> of 100000 sorted words and another List<string> of 10000 prefixes. So 10000 calls of Where operator are taking too much time. So I've decided to use BinarySearch. Does this decision has any sense?

Comment: @sword no, because `BinarySearch` only returns one index, and you'd have to sort the array for each prefix, which would take longer than a linear search.

Comment: @DStanley, and what if I got all prefixes and all words that start by one letter? So I have no need to sort array

Comment: You could implement your own BinarySearch to find the first item that matches your prefix and then scan while the prefix still matches.

Comment: @DStanley, So it is impossible to get first suitable index and then set start search index for BinarySearch?

Comment: `BinarySearch` does not help you because it returns _one_ index (and not necessarily the _first_ index).

Comment: @DStanley, I see. Thank you. However I still don't know how to solve my task)

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to create your own StartsWithComparer:

```
class StartsWithComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    public int Compare(string a, string b) {
        if(a.StartsWith(b)) {
            return 0;
        }
        return a.CompareTo(b);
    }
}
```

As others pointed out, this will only return one index.  You can have a couple of helpers to return all items:

```
IEnumerable<string> GetBefore(IList<string> sorted, int foundIndex, string prefix) {
    for(var i = foundIndex - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if(sorted[i].StartsWith(prefix)) {
            yield return sorted[i];
        }
    }
}

IEnumerable<string> GetCurrentAndAfter(IList<string> sorted, int foundIndex, string prefix) {
    for(var i = foundIndex; i < sorted.Count; i++) {
        if(sorted[i].StartsWith(prefix)) {
            yield return sorted[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Then to use it:

```
var index = sorted.BinarySearch("asdf", new StartsWithComparer());
var previous = GetBefore(sorted, index, "asdf");
var currentAndAfter = GetCurrentAndAfter(sorted, index, "asdf");
```

You can wrap the whole thing in your own class, with a single method that returns all items that start with your prefix.