# VB.NET: sorting list by another list

Tags: vb.net

How to sort `somelist As List(of T)` by the order set in another list `sortorder As List(of Integer)`? Both `somelist` and `sortorder` are of the same size and are indexed from 0 to n. Integers in the `sortorder` list determine the sort order: new index of item X in `somelist` = value of item X in `sortorder`.

Like this:

```
somelist = (itemA, itemB, itemC)
sortorder = (3, 1, 2)
somelist.sort()
somelist = (itemB, itemC, itemA)
```

I am trying to sort several equally sized lists using the predefined sort order.

Comment: I'm going to guess the elegant answer involves Linq...you may want to add that tag.

Comment: The question is not clear because of the expected result. If the content of the `sortorder`-list  specifies the value used for the sorting then item1=3,item2=1,item3=2. So the result should be(ascending): item2,item3,item1.

Comment: @TimSchmelter you are right, my bad. I've edited the example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use LINQ, although i hate [the ugly method syntax in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9039282/284240):

```
somelist = somelist.
    Select(Function(t, index) New With {.Obj = t, .Index = index}).
    OrderBy(Function(x) sortorder(x.Index)).
    Select(Function(x) x.Obj).
    ToList()
```

This uses the overload of [`Enumerable.Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534869(v=vs.100).aspx) that projects the index of the item. The object and the index are stored in an anonymous type which is used for the ordering, finally i'm selecting the object and use `ToList` to build the ordered list.

Another way is to use [`Enumerable.Zip`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) to merge both into an anonymous type:

```
Dim q = From x In somelist.Zip(sortorder, Function(t, sort) New With {.Obj = t, .Sort = sort})
        Order By x.Sort Ascending
        Select x.Obj 
somelist = q.ToList()
```

If you want to order it descending, so the highest values first, use `OrderByDescending` in the method syntax and `Order By x.Sort Descending` in the query.

But why do you store such related informations in two different collections at all?

Comment: actually there're many different collections and sometimes they are related, sometimes not. I was hoping to be able to perform the sort without merging the related collections.

Comment: @kutas: above does not really merge them. They are just linked in the query to lookup the sorting value via index. The original collections  are not modified apart from the list that you want to sort.

Comment: I've ended up using the second solution. Thanks!