# how split list of numbers and add "," after each number

Tags: .net, vb.net

i have lists of phone numbers each phone number must have 10 numbers, i want simple code to add "," after every phone number to i can send it in SMS application.

i have it in this way :

0123456789

0123456789

0123456789

0123456789

0123456789

0123456789

i want the output look like this :

0123456789,0123456789,0123456789,0123456789,0123456789,0123456789

```
orig = "012345678901234567890123456789"
Dim res = Enumerable.Range(0,orig.Length\10).[Select](Function(i) orig.Substring(i*8,8))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you have a single string which contains all numbers? Strange. However....

```
Dim orig = "012345678901234567890123456789"
Dim allNumbers As New List(Of String)
For i As Int32 = 0 To orig.Length - 1 Step 10
    Dim number As String
    If i + 10 >= orig.Length Then
        number = orig.Substring(i)
    Else
        number = orig.Substring(i, 10)
    End If
    allNumbers.Add(number)
Next
```

Now you can use [`String.Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
Dim result = String.Join(",", allNumbers)  ' 0123456789,0123456789,0123456789
```

This is the most efficient approach and it is also readable. If you insist on a  LINQ approach, here it is ([method syntax ugly as always in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9039282/284240)):

```
Dim numGroups = orig.
    Select(Function(chr, index) New With {.Char = chr, .Index = index}).
    GroupBy(Function(x) x.Index \ 10).
    Select(Function(g) String.Concat(g.Select(Function(x) x.Char)))
Dim result = String.Join(",", numGroups)
```

The trick is to group by `x.Index \ 10` which is integer division in VB.NET, the decimal part is truncated, so it builds groups of ten.

Comment: thanks the first code work , but the second i have error in orig. , i think i need to import something , but i don't know what it is

Comment: @RabeeaQabaha: that's a LINQ query, you need to use at least VS 2008 and add `Imports System.Linq`.

Answer (score 1):

The [String.join()](http://www.dotnetperls.com/join-vbnet) function is probably the one you are looking for.

See [the official documentation on MSDN website](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).