# What is the difference between Linq and EF syntax?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

What is difference of

Linq: `var data=from a in context.object select a;`

EF:  `var data=context.object().Tolist();`

Comment: That link isn't very good.

Comment: [Fluent and Query Expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/214500/linq-fluent-and-query-expression-is-there-any-benefits-of-one-over-other)

Answer (score 3):

They are both LINQ.

The first is *query (expression) syntax*

   `IEnumerable<int> numQuery1 = 
                    from num in numbers
                    where num % 2 == 0
                    orderby num
                    select num;`

And the other is *method syntax* 

   `IEnumerable<int> numQuery2 = numbers
                .Where(num => num % 2 == 0)
                .OrderBy(n => n);`

Source: [MSDN: Query Syntax and Method Syntax in LINQ (C#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397947.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

In your case the difference is that in first case data will be of lazy `IEnumerable` type and and will be executed on enumerating it.

Second example will enumerate colletion to a list and collection will be in memory after execution of `ToList` method.

But I assume you are interested in difference between LINQ operators like `from`, `where`, `select` and method `Where`, `Select`, etc. There is not difference as operators are compiled to methods.

Comment: Yes, Andrii, my confusion is we have two kind of syntax for EF one is linq and another is EF it self, so I got confusion that when to use which one?

Comment: @Kinnal, choose which ever you like best. They are identical at runtime. Personally, I prefer method call chain approach.

Comment: @Kinnal - it's not "ef it self" they are two different syntax's, that's it. Use which ever you prefer. LINQ or Lambda.

Comment: @Phill both are Linq queries, either Query or Fluent Syntax. In my view its confusing to call just one Linq. Lambda are integral part of the Linq Fluent syntax.

Comment: @AndriiLitvinov what is `lazy IEnumerable`, I think you are pointing to deferred execution, which is also the case for IQueryable, in fact that's what both cases are, just in second call `ToList()` is called

Comment: @MrinalKamboj, yes, you are right, I mean deferred execution.

Answer (score 0):

**Difference between both syntax is**:

- Your 1st query is LINQ to Sql and 2nd one is Entity SQL.
- Entity SQL is processed by the Entity Framework Object Services directly
- Entity SQL returns ObjectQuery instead of IQueryable

Comment: He question is about LINQ vs Lambda syntax.

Comment: Why first call is not EF call, he's just accessing the db context

Answer (score 0):

You mean to know the kinds of difference in query syntax while Entity Framework.

**[Basics of LINQ & Lamda Expressions](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33769/Basics-of-LINQ-Lamda-Expressions)**

**LINQ**

Linq is the Microsoft's first attempt to integrate queries into language. We know, it is really easy to find data from sql objects simply writing a query while its somewhat hectic when we want to do the same thing in a DataTable or Lists. Generally we will have to loop through every elements to find the exact match, if there is some aggregation we need to aggregate the values etc. Linq provides an easy way to write queries that can run with the in memory objects.

**[Lamda](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx)**

A lambda expression is an anonymous function that you can use to create delegates or expression tree types. By using lambda expressions, you can write local functions that can be passed as arguments or returned as the value of function calls. Lambda expressions are particularly helpful for writing LINQ query expressions.

Hope it Helps.

Comment: Lambda are integral part of the Linq fluent syntax, so the definitions provided are indeed misleading