# How can I obtain a directory's file list sorted by timestamp?

Tags: vb.net, linq, sorting, timestamp

I am stuck on this sorting problem.

```
    Private Sub ...
        Dim oDirInfo As DirectoryInfo
        Dim aoFSInfo() As FileSystemInfo
        Dim asFiles() As String
```

FQPN is a fully qualified path name ending in "\*.*".

```
        oDirInfo = New DirectoryInfo(FQPN)
```

Now into asFiles I want the files' names, sorted by the files' timestamps in ascending order. I presume, that `oDirInfo.CreationTime` plays a role here, but can not figure out how to use `OrderBy` properly.

```
        aoFSInfo = oDirInfo.GetFileSystemInfos()    '?
        asFiles = aoFSInfo.OrderBy(...)
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's LINQ and you can use this (method-)syntax:

```
asFiles = oFSInfo.
    OrderBy(Function(fsi) fsi.CreationTime).
    Select(Function(fsi) fsi.FullName).
    ToArray()
```

If you don't like the [ugly `Function` keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9039282/284240) you can use query syntax:

```
Dim orderedFiles = From fsi In oFSInfo
                   Order by fsi.iCreationTime Ascending
                   Select fsi.FullName
asFiles = orderedFiles.ToArray()
```

Even if these are two statements it's not slower than method syntax due to *deferred* execution.

Comment: When using the query syntax you can put () around the query and append .ToArray.

Comment: @dbasnett: yes, but that would destroy readability which was the reason to split it into two. There is no reason to avoid a second statement. It even enables to reuse the query if desired.

Comment: @TimSchmelter. Small typo I can't correct due to being just 3 letters in total. Twice cosmetical: `oFSInfo` instead of `aoFSInfo` to reflect the variable in the OP; once syntactical: the member `iCreationTime` should read `CreationTime`. -  Maybe not too important, but I'd probably go for the full declaration  `Dim orderedFiles As IEnumerable(Of String) ...` - Otherwise: Thanks for your answer.