# Writing linq queries with the dot expression

Tags: linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I have to support linq code that looks like the one below

```
        public async Task<IEnumerable<UserProfiles>> GetUserProfileByIdAsync(IEnumerable<string> ids)
        {
          .AsQueryable()
          .Where(sea => ids.Contains(sea.UserId))
          .Distinct()
          .ToListAsync()
        }
```

I am only used to writing my linq like this

```
        var query = 
          from car in cars
          join manufacturer in manufacturers ....
```

what is the difference between the two queries and any link to tutorials 
where one can learn how to write the first query with the dots will be 
apreciated.

Comment: Asking for tutorials is off-topic here.

Comment: Also, here's a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214500/fluent-and-query-expression-is-there-any-benefits-of-one-over-other?noredirect=1&lq=1