# Difference between using IQueryable and local variable for LINQ Query

Tags: c#, linq

I have written a LINQ Query to perform a simple where query against a database.  However, I noticed there are two methods of doing this, the first I picked up from a book and the second is what I'm seeing mainly online:

First

```
    IQueryable<WebApi.Models.User>? users = db.Users?
        .Where(user => user.EmailAddress.Equals(loginRequest.EmailAddress) && user.Password.Equals(loginRequest.Password));
```

Second

```
    WebApi.Models.User user = (from u in db.Users
                where u.EmailAddress.Equals(loginRequest.EmailAddress) && u.Password.Equals(loginRequest.Password)
                select u).SingleOrDefault();
```

The first uses the IQueryable interface while the second does not.  What is the difference between the two and does IQueryable provide any advantages over the local variable method?

Comment: BTW, for readability you can use `==` instead of `.Equals()`.

Comment: An `IQueryable<T>` represents a (non-executed) query, not its results. Methods like `ToList`, `SingleOrDefault`, `Count`, etc will _materialize_ and actually execute the query.

Comment: Would it be reasonable to then assume that iQueryable is better for larger result sets?  I am deciding which I should use throughout my project.

Comment: Your two methods are not directly comparable. One returns multiple values, the other returns a single value. If in your first example you followed up with `WebApi.Models.User user = users.SingleOrDefault()` the two would be completely equivalent, and it wouldn't matter if you used an intermediate variable for the query or not.

Comment: @DStanley - Thanks, that's exactly what I needed to know, if they would be identical or not if they both return a single result.

Comment: Yes they would - the second is actually using `IQueryable` too, you just don't see it because you've tacked on a `SingleOrDefault` to get a single result.

Comment: Musaffar, look up "query syntax" and "fluent syntax" for LINQ. I prefer fluent syntax.  Check this out too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214500/fluent-and-query-expression-is-there-any-benefits-of-one-over-other